# How to convert number to words in java

Tags: java, math, numbers, jscience

We currently have a crude mechanism to convert numbers to words (e.g. using a few static arrays) and based on the size of the number translating that into an english text. But we are running into issues for numbers which are huge.

```
10183 = Ten thousand one hundred eighty three
90 = Ninety
5888 = Five thousand eight hundred eighty eight
```

Is there an easy to use function in any of the math libraries which I can use for this purpose?

Comment: Here is the online tool that might be useful to you:  https://helloacm.com/tools/convert-arabic-numerals-to-english-words/

Comment: This might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911966/how-to-convert-number-to-words-in-java/62600424#62600424

Answer (score 125, accepted):

[Here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0426.html) is the code, I don't think there is any method in SE.

It basically converts number to string and parses String and associates it with the weight

**for example**

```
1000
```

`1` is treated as thousand position and `1` gets mapped to `"one"` and thousand because of position

This is the code from the website:

**English**

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class EnglishNumberToWords {

  private static final String[] tensNames = {
    "",
    " ten",
    " twenty",
    " thirty",
    " forty",
    " fifty",
    " sixty",
    " seventy",
    " eighty",
    " ninety"
  };

  private static final String[] numNames = {
    "",
    " one",
    " two",
    " three",
    " four",
    " five",
    " six",
    " seven",
    " eight",
    " nine",
    " ten",
    " eleven",
    " twelve",
    " thirteen",
    " fourteen",
    " fifteen",
    " sixteen",
    " seventeen",
    " eighteen",
    " nineteen"
  };

  private EnglishNumberToWords() {}

  private static String convertLessThanOneThousand(int number) {
    String soFar;

    if (number % 100 < 20){
      soFar = numNames[number % 100];
      number /= 100;
    }
    else {
      soFar = numNames[number % 10];
      number /= 10;

      soFar = tensNames[number % 10] + soFar;
      number /= 10;
    }
    if (number == 0) return soFar;
    return numNames[number] + " hundred" + soFar;
  }


  public static String convert(long number) {
    // 0 to 999 999 999 999
    if (number == 0) { return "zero"; }

    String snumber = Long.toString(number);

    // pad with "0"
    String mask = "000000000000";
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(mask);
    snumber = df.format(number);

    // XXXnnnnnnnnn
    int billions = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(0,3));
    // nnnXXXnnnnnn
    int millions  = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(3,6));
    // nnnnnnXXXnnn
    int hundredThousands = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(6,9));
    // nnnnnnnnnXXX
    int thousands = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(9,12));

    String tradBillions;
    switch (billions) {
    case 0:
      tradBillions = "";
      break;
    case 1 :
      tradBillions = convertLessThanOneThousand(billions)
      + " billion ";
      break;
    default :
      tradBillions = convertLessThanOneThousand(billions)
      + " billion ";
    }
    String result =  tradBillions;

    String tradMillions;
    switch (millions) {
    case 0:
      tradMillions = "";
      break;
    case 1 :
      tradMillions = convertLessThanOneThousand(millions)
         + " million ";
      break;
    default :
      tradMillions = convertLessThanOneThousand(millions)
         + " million ";
    }
    result =  result + tradMillions;

    String tradHundredThousands;
    switch (hundredThousands) {
    case 0:
      tradHundredThousands = "";
      break;
    case 1 :
      tradHundredThousands = "one thousand ";
      break;
    default :
      tradHundredThousands = convertLessThanOneThousand(hundredThousands)
         + " thousand ";
    }
    result =  result + tradHundredThousands;

    String tradThousand;
    tradThousand = convertLessThanOneThousand(thousands);
    result =  result + tradThousand;

    // remove extra spaces!
    return result.replaceAll("^\\s+", "").replaceAll("\\b\\s{2,}\\b", " ");
  }

  /**
   * testing
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(0));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(1));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(16));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(100));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(118));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(200));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(219));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(800));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(801));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(1316));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(1000000));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(2000000));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(3000200));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(700000));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(9000000));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(9001000));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(123456789));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(2147483647));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(3000000010L));

    /*
     *** zero
     *** one
     *** sixteen
     *** one hundred
     *** one hundred eighteen
     *** two hundred
     *** two hundred nineteen
     *** eight hundred
     *** eight hundred one
     *** one thousand three hundred sixteen
     *** one million
     *** two millions
     *** three millions two hundred
     *** seven hundred thousand
     *** nine millions
     *** nine millions one thousand
     *** one hundred twenty three millions four hundred
     **      fifty six thousand seven hundred eighty nine
     *** two billion one hundred forty seven millions
     **      four hundred eighty three thousand six hundred forty seven
     *** three billion ten
     **/
  }
}
```

**Français**
Quite different than the english version but french is a lot more difficult!

```
package com.rgagnon.howto;

import java.text.*;

class FrenchNumberToWords {
  private static final String[] dizaineNames = {
    "",
    "",
    "vingt",
    "trente",
    "quarante",
    "cinquante",
    "soixante",
    "soixante",
    "quatre-vingt",
    "quatre-vingt"
  };

  private static final String[] uniteNames1 = {
    "",
    "un",
    "deux",
    "trois",
    "quatre",
    "cinq",
    "six",
    "sept",
    "huit",
    "neuf",
    "dix",
    "onze",
    "douze",
    "treize",
    "quatorze",
    "quinze",
    "seize",
    "dix-sept",
    "dix-huit",
    "dix-neuf"
  };

  private static final String[] uniteNames2 = {
    "",
    "",
    "deux",
    "trois",
    "quatre",
    "cinq",
    "six",
    "sept",
    "huit",
    "neuf",
    "dix"
  };

  private FrenchNumberToWords() {}

  private static String convertZeroToHundred(int number) {

    int laDizaine = number / 10;
    int lUnite = number % 10;
    String resultat = "";

    switch (laDizaine) {
    case 1 :
    case 7 :
    case 9 :
      lUnite = lUnite + 10;
      break;
    default:
    }

    // séparateur "-" "et"  ""
    String laLiaison = "";
    if (laDizaine > 1) {
      laLiaison = "-";
    }
    // cas particuliers
    switch (lUnite) {
    case 0:
      laLiaison = "";
      break;
    case 1 :
      if (laDizaine == 8) {
        laLiaison = "-";
      }
      else {
        laLiaison = " et ";
      }
      break;
    case 11 :
      if (laDizaine==7) {
        laLiaison = " et ";
      }
      break;
    default:
    }

    // dizaines en lettres
    switch (laDizaine) {
    case 0:
      resultat = uniteNames1[lUnite];
      break;
    case 8 :
      if (lUnite == 0) {
        resultat = dizaineNames[laDizaine];
      }
      else {
        resultat = dizaineNames[laDizaine]
                                + laLiaison + uniteNames1[lUnite];
      }
      break;
    default :
      resultat = dizaineNames[laDizaine]
                              + laLiaison + uniteNames1[lUnite];
    }
    return resultat;
  }

  private static String convertLessThanOneThousand(int number) {

    int lesCentaines = number / 100;
    int leReste = number % 100;
    String sReste = convertZeroToHundred(leReste);

    String resultat;
    switch (lesCentaines) {
    case 0:
      resultat = sReste;
      break;
    case 1 :
      if (leReste > 0) {
        resultat = "cent " + sReste;
      }
      else {
        resultat = "cent";
      }
      break;
    default :
      if (leReste > 0) {
        resultat = uniteNames2[lesCentaines] + " cent " + sReste;
      }
      else {
        resultat = uniteNames2[lesCentaines] + " cents";
      }
    }
    return resultat;
  }

  public static String convert(long number) {
    // 0 à 999 999 999 999
    if (number == 0) { return "zéro"; }

    String snumber = Long.toString(number);

    // pad des "0"
    String mask = "000000000000";
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(mask);
    snumber = df.format(number);

    // XXXnnnnnnnnn
    int lesMilliards = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(0,3));
    // nnnXXXnnnnnn
    int lesMillions  = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(3,6));
    // nnnnnnXXXnnn
    int lesCentMille = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(6,9));
    // nnnnnnnnnXXX
    int lesMille = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(9,12));

    String tradMilliards;
    switch (lesMilliards) {
    case 0:
      tradMilliards = "";
      break;
    case 1 :
      tradMilliards = convertLessThanOneThousand(lesMilliards)
         + " milliard ";
      break;
    default :
      tradMilliards = convertLessThanOneThousand(lesMilliards)
         + " milliards ";
    }
    String resultat =  tradMilliards;

    String tradMillions;
    switch (lesMillions) {
    case 0:
      tradMillions = "";
      break;
    case 1 :
      tradMillions = convertLessThanOneThousand(lesMillions)
         + " million ";
      break;
    default :
      tradMillions = convertLessThanOneThousand(lesMillions)
         + " millions ";
    }
    resultat =  resultat + tradMillions;

    String tradCentMille;
    switch (lesCentMille) {
    case 0:
      tradCentMille = "";
      break;
    case 1 :
      tradCentMille = "mille ";
      break;
    default :
      tradCentMille = convertLessThanOneThousand(lesCentMille)
         + " mille ";
    }
    resultat =  resultat + tradCentMille;

    String tradMille;
    tradMille = convertLessThanOneThousand(lesMille);
    resultat =  resultat + tradMille;

    return resultat;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("*** " + FrenchNumberToWords.convert(0));
    System.out.println("*** " + FrenchNumberToWords.convert(9));
    System.out.println("*** " + FrenchNumberToWords.convert(19));
    System.out.println("*** " + FrenchNumberToWords.convert(21));
    System.out.println("*** " + FrenchNumberToWords.convert(28));
    System.out.println("*** " + FrenchNumberToWords.convert(71));
    System.out.println("*** " + FrenchNumberToWords.convert(72));
    System.out.println("*** " + FrenchNumberToWords.convert(80));
    System.out.println("*** " + FrenchNumberToWords.convert(81));
    System.out.println("*** " + FrenchNumberToWords.convert(89));
    System.out.println("*** " + FrenchNumberToWords.convert(90));
    System.out.println("*** " + FrenchNumberToWords.convert(91));
    System.out.println("*** " + FrenchNumberToWords.convert(97));
    System.out.println("*** " + FrenchNumberToWords.convert(100));
    System.out.println("*** " + FrenchNumberToWords.convert(101));
    System.out.println("*** " + FrenchNumberToWords.convert(110));
    System.out.println("*** " + FrenchNumberToWords.convert(120));
    System.out.println("*** " + FrenchNumberToWords.convert(200));
    System.out.println("*** " + FrenchNumberToWords.convert(201));
    System.out.println("*** " + FrenchNumberToWords.convert(232));
    System.out.println("*** " + FrenchNumberToWords.convert(999));
    System.out.println("*** " + FrenchNumberToWords.convert(1000));
    System.out.println("*** " + FrenchNumberToWords.convert(1001));
    System.out.println("*** " + FrenchNumberToWords.convert(10000));
    System.out.println("*** " + FrenchNumberToWords.convert(10001));
    System.out.println("*** " + FrenchNumberToWords.convert(100000));
    System.out.println("*** " + FrenchNumberToWords.convert(2000000));
    System.out.println("*** " + FrenchNumberToWords.convert(3000000000L));
    System.out.println("*** " + FrenchNumberToWords.convert(2147483647));
    /*
     *** OUTPUT
     *** zéro
     *** neuf
     *** dix-neuf
     *** vingt et un
     *** vingt-huit
     *** soixante et onze
     *** soixante-douze
     *** quatre-vingt
     *** quatre-vingt-un
     *** quatre-vingt-neuf
     *** quatre-vingt-dix
     *** quatre-vingt-onze
     *** quatre-vingt-dix-sept
     *** cent
     *** cent un
     *** cent dix
     *** cent vingt
     *** deux cents
     *** deux cent un
     *** deux cent trente-deux
     *** neuf cent quatre-vingt-dix-neuf
     *** mille
     *** mille un
     *** dix mille
     *** dix mille un
     *** cent mille
     *** deux millions
     *** trois milliards
     *** deux milliards cent quarante-sept millions
     **          quatre cent quatre-vingt-trois mille six cent quarante-sept
     */
  }
}
```

You can handle "dollar and cent" conversion by calling the "convert" method two times.

```
String phrase = "12345.67" ;
Float num = new Float( phrase ) ;
int dollars = (int)Math.floor( num ) ;
int cent = (int)Math.floor( ( num - dollars ) * 100.0f ) ;

String s = "$ " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert( dollars ) + " and "
           + EnglishNumberToWords.convert( cent ) + " cents" ;
```

Another way to use a built-in function of your DBMS (if available).
For **Oracle**

```
SQL> select to_char(to_date(873,'J'), 'JSP') as converted_form from dual;

CONVERTED_FORM
---------------------------
EIGHT HUNDRED SEVENTY-THREE

SQL>
'JSP' means :
J : the Julian format.
SP : spells the word for the number passed to to_date
```

Comment: Limited method: it does not convert large numbers neither supports decimal numbers.

Comment: While this answer is over 3 years old, it would be helpful if you could include essential parts of the link here in the event that link ever fails to be available.

Comment: I've taken your code for the french version and ported it to groovy while making it work for bigger numbers. It's pretty easy to make it work with even bigger ones. In case someone's interested, it's [here](https://gist.github.com/alainperry/d473644986770eff111b56711b484207). Thanks for the base material !

Comment: Program gives wrong output when you enter 100500 but in rest cases works fine

Comment: @adeshsingh while you are right there. could you fix the code and update the answer. this was ~7 year old code

Comment: Can anybody update this code to convert decimal numbers also?

Answer (score 74):

[ICU4J](http://site.icu-project.org/home) contains nice number-spellout support. The files with the "rules" can be easily edited, and it's no problem to add other languages (we did it e.g. for Polish and Russian).

Comment: ICU4J's data comes from CLDR http://unicode.org/cldr/ and already supports Polish and Russian. http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/rbnf/ Did you file a ticket if you found issues with the existing rules?

Comment: No, but we did this some years ago, and if I remember right, we needed some additional things. But good to know!

Comment: RBNF has had major overhauls a year or so ago, both in CLDR and ICU. Check it out.

Comment: _This_ should be the selected answer since the others depend on bug ridden and unlocalized example implementations

Comment: Yes! This should be an selected answer... It worked like a charm... It translates to any language, any region, any country as listed here http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry..  The usage is as simple as.        `RuleBasedNumberFormat ruleBasedNumberFormat = new RuleBasedNumberFormat( new Locale("EN", "US"), RuleBasedNumberFormat.SPELLOUT );        
          System.out.println(ruleBasedNumberFormat.format(value));`

Answer (score 63):

Because you cannot have a general algorithm for every locale, no. You have to implement your own algorithm for every locale that you are supporting.

** **EDIT** **

Just for the heck of it, I played around until I got this class. <del>It cannot display `Long.MIN_VALUE` because of bit restrictions... but I presume it could be modified and change `long` value types to `double` for decimal or even bigger numbers</del> It can display any numbers up to 66 digits and 26 decimals using a string representation of the number. You may add more `ScaleUnit` for more decimals...

```
/**
 * This class will convert numeric values into an english representation
 * 
 * For units, see : http://www.jimloy.com/math/billion.htm
 * 
 * @author yanick.rochon@gmail.com
 */
public class NumberToWords {

    static public class ScaleUnit {
        private int exponent;
        private String[] names;
        private ScaleUnit(int exponent, String...names) {
            this.exponent = exponent;
            this.names = names;
        }
        public int getExponent() {
            return exponent;
        }
        public String getName(int index) {
            return names[index];
        }
    }

    /**
     * See http://www.wordiq.com/definition/Names_of_large_numbers
     */
    static private ScaleUnit[] SCALE_UNITS = new ScaleUnit[] {
        new ScaleUnit(63, "vigintillion", "decilliard"),
        new ScaleUnit(60, "novemdecillion", "decillion"),
        new ScaleUnit(57, "octodecillion", "nonilliard"),
        new ScaleUnit(54, "septendecillion", "nonillion"),
        new ScaleUnit(51, "sexdecillion", "octilliard"),
        new ScaleUnit(48, "quindecillion", "octillion"),
        new ScaleUnit(45, "quattuordecillion", "septilliard"),
        new ScaleUnit(42, "tredecillion", "septillion"),
        new ScaleUnit(39, "duodecillion", "sextilliard"),
        new ScaleUnit(36, "undecillion", "sextillion"),
        new ScaleUnit(33, "decillion", "quintilliard"),
        new ScaleUnit(30, "nonillion", "quintillion"),
        new ScaleUnit(27, "octillion", "quadrilliard"),
        new ScaleUnit(24, "septillion", "quadrillion"),
        new ScaleUnit(21, "sextillion", "trilliard"),
        new ScaleUnit(18, "quintillion", "trillion"),
        new ScaleUnit(15, "quadrillion", "billiard"),
        new ScaleUnit(12, "trillion", "billion"),
        new ScaleUnit(9, "billion", "milliard"),
        new ScaleUnit(6, "million", "million"),
        new ScaleUnit(3, "thousand", "thousand"),
        new ScaleUnit(2, "hundred", "hundred"),
        //new ScaleUnit(1, "ten", "ten"),
        //new ScaleUnit(0, "one", "one"),
        new ScaleUnit(-1, "tenth", "tenth"),
        new ScaleUnit(-2, "hundredth", "hundredth"),
        new ScaleUnit(-3, "thousandth", "thousandth"),
        new ScaleUnit(-4, "ten-thousandth", "ten-thousandth"),
        new ScaleUnit(-5, "hundred-thousandth", "hundred-thousandth"),
        new ScaleUnit(-6, "millionth", "millionth"),
        new ScaleUnit(-7, "ten-millionth", "ten-millionth"),
        new ScaleUnit(-8, "hundred-millionth", "hundred-millionth"),
        new ScaleUnit(-9, "billionth", "milliardth"),
        new ScaleUnit(-10, "ten-billionth", "ten-milliardth"),
        new ScaleUnit(-11, "hundred-billionth", "hundred-milliardth"),
        new ScaleUnit(-12, "trillionth", "billionth"),
        new ScaleUnit(-13, "ten-trillionth", "ten-billionth"),
        new ScaleUnit(-14, "hundred-trillionth", "hundred-billionth"),
        new ScaleUnit(-15, "quadrillionth", "billiardth"),
        new ScaleUnit(-16, "ten-quadrillionth", "ten-billiardth"),
        new ScaleUnit(-17, "hundred-quadrillionth", "hundred-billiardth"),
        new ScaleUnit(-18, "quintillionth", "trillionth"),
        new ScaleUnit(-19, "ten-quintillionth", "ten-trillionth"),
        new ScaleUnit(-20, "hundred-quintillionth", "hundred-trillionth"),
        new ScaleUnit(-21, "sextillionth", "trilliardth"),
        new ScaleUnit(-22, "ten-sextillionth", "ten-trilliardth"),
        new ScaleUnit(-23, "hundred-sextillionth", "hundred-trilliardth"),
        new ScaleUnit(-24, "septillionth","quadrillionth"),
        new ScaleUnit(-25, "ten-septillionth","ten-quadrillionth"),
        new ScaleUnit(-26, "hundred-septillionth","hundred-quadrillionth"),
    };

    static public enum Scale {
        SHORT,
        LONG;

        public String getName(int exponent) {
            for (ScaleUnit unit : SCALE_UNITS) {
                if (unit.getExponent() == exponent) {
                    return unit.getName(this.ordinal());
                }
            }
            return ""; 
        }
    }

    /**
     * Change this scale to support American and modern British value (short scale)
     * or Traditional British value (long scale)
     */
    static public Scale SCALE = Scale.SHORT; 


    static abstract public class AbstractProcessor {

        static protected final String SEPARATOR = " ";
        static protected final int NO_VALUE = -1;

        protected List<Integer> getDigits(long value) {
            ArrayList<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            if (value == 0) {
                digits.add(0);
            } else {
                while (value > 0) {
                    digits.add(0, (int) value % 10);
                    value /= 10;
                }
            }
            return digits;
        }

        public String getName(long value) {
            return getName(Long.toString(value));
        }

        public String getName(double value) {
            return getName(Double.toString(value));
        }

        abstract public String getName(String value);
    }

    static public class UnitProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

        static private final String[] TOKENS = new String[] {
            "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine",
            "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"
        };

        @Override
        public String getName(String value) {
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

            int offset = NO_VALUE;
            int number;
            if (value.length() > 3) {
                number = Integer.valueOf(value.substring(value.length() - 3), 10);
            } else {
                number = Integer.valueOf(value, 10);
            }
            number %= 100;
            if (number < 10) {
                offset = (number % 10) - 1;
                //number /= 10;
            } else if (number < 20) {
                offset = (number % 20) - 1;
                //number /= 100;
            }

            if (offset != NO_VALUE && offset < TOKENS.length) {
                buffer.append(TOKENS[offset]);
            }

            return buffer.toString();
        }

    }

    static public class TensProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

        static private final String[] TOKENS = new String[] {
            "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"
        };

        static private final String UNION_SEPARATOR = "-";

        private UnitProcessor unitProcessor = new UnitProcessor();

        @Override
        public String getName(String value) {
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            boolean tensFound = false;

            int number;
            if (value.length() > 3) {
                number = Integer.valueOf(value.substring(value.length() - 3), 10);
            } else {
                number = Integer.valueOf(value, 10);
            }
            number %= 100;   // keep only two digits
            if (number >= 20) {
                buffer.append(TOKENS[(number / 10) - 2]);
                number %= 10;
                tensFound = true;
            } else {
                number %= 20;
            }

            if (number != 0) {
                if (tensFound) {
                    buffer.append(UNION_SEPARATOR);
                }
                buffer.append(unitProcessor.getName(number));
            }

            return buffer.toString();
        }
    }

    static public class HundredProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

        private int EXPONENT = 2;

        private UnitProcessor unitProcessor = new UnitProcessor();
        private TensProcessor tensProcessor = new TensProcessor();

        @Override
        public String getName(String value) {
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

            int number;
            if (value.isEmpty()) {
                number = 0;
            } else if (value.length() > 4) {
                number = Integer.valueOf(value.substring(value.length() - 4), 10);
            } else {
                number = Integer.valueOf(value, 10);
            }
            number %= 1000;  // keep at least three digits

            if (number >= 100) {
                buffer.append(unitProcessor.getName(number / 100));
                buffer.append(SEPARATOR);
                buffer.append(SCALE.getName(EXPONENT));
            }

            String tensName = tensProcessor.getName(number % 100);

            if (!tensName.isEmpty() && (number >= 100)) {
                buffer.append(SEPARATOR);
            }
            buffer.append(tensName);

            return buffer.toString();
        }
    }

    static public class CompositeBigProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

        private HundredProcessor hundredProcessor = new HundredProcessor();
        private AbstractProcessor lowProcessor;
        private int exponent;

        public CompositeBigProcessor(int exponent) {
            if (exponent <= 3) {
                lowProcessor = hundredProcessor;
            } else {
                lowProcessor = new CompositeBigProcessor(exponent - 3);
            }
            this.exponent = exponent;
        }

        public String getToken() {
            return SCALE.getName(getPartDivider());
        }

        protected AbstractProcessor getHighProcessor() {
            return hundredProcessor;
        }

        protected AbstractProcessor getLowProcessor() {
            return lowProcessor;
        }

        public int getPartDivider() {
            return exponent;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName(String value) {
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

            String high, low;
            if (value.length() < getPartDivider()) {
                high = "";
                low = value;
            } else {
                int index = value.length() - getPartDivider();
                high = value.substring(0, index);
                low = value.substring(index);
            }

            String highName = getHighProcessor().getName(high);
            String lowName = getLowProcessor().getName(low);

            if (!highName.isEmpty()) {
                buffer.append(highName);
                buffer.append(SEPARATOR);
                buffer.append(getToken());

                if (!lowName.isEmpty()) {
                    buffer.append(SEPARATOR);
                }
            }

            if (!lowName.isEmpty()) {
                buffer.append(lowName);
            }

            return buffer.toString();
        }
    }

    static public class DefaultProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

        static private String MINUS = "minus";
        static private String UNION_AND = "and";

        static private String ZERO_TOKEN = "zero";

        private AbstractProcessor processor = new CompositeBigProcessor(63);

        @Override
        public String getName(String value) {
            boolean negative = false;
            if (value.startsWith("-")) {
                negative = true;
                value = value.substring(1);
            }

            int decimals = value.indexOf(".");
            String decimalValue = null;
            if (0 <= decimals) {
                decimalValue = value.substring(decimals + 1);
                value = value.substring(0, decimals);
            }

            String name = processor.getName(value);

            if (name.isEmpty()) {
                name = ZERO_TOKEN;
            } else if (negative) {
                name = MINUS.concat(SEPARATOR).concat(name); 
            }

            if (!(null == decimalValue || decimalValue.isEmpty())) {
                name = name.concat(SEPARATOR).concat(UNION_AND).concat(SEPARATOR)
                    .concat(processor.getName(decimalValue))
                    .concat(SEPARATOR).concat(SCALE.getName(-decimalValue.length()));
            }

            return name;
        }

    }

    static public AbstractProcessor processor;


    public static void main(String...args) {

        processor = new DefaultProcessor();

        long[] values = new long[] {
            0,
            4,
            10,
            12,
            100,
            108,
            299,
            1000,
            1003,
            2040,
            45213,
            100000,
            100005,
            100010,
            202020,
            202022,
            999999,
            1000000,
            1000001,
            10000000,
            10000007,
            99999999,
            Long.MAX_VALUE,
            Long.MIN_VALUE
        };

        String[] strValues = new String[] {
            "0001.2",
            "3.141592"
        };

        for (long val : values) {
            System.out.println(val + " = " + processor.getName(val) );
        }

        for (String strVal : strValues) {
            System.out.println(strVal + " = " + processor.getName(strVal) );
        }

        // generate a very big number...
        StringBuilder bigNumber = new StringBuilder();
        for (int d=0; d<66; d++) {
            bigNumber.append( (char) ((Math.random() * 10) + '0'));
        }
        bigNumber.append(".");
        for (int d=0; d<26; d++) {
            bigNumber.append( (char) ((Math.random() * 10) + '0'));
        }

        System.out.println(bigNumber.toString() + " = " + processor.getName(bigNumber.toString()));

    }

}
```

and a sample output (for the random big number generator)

```
0 = zero
4 = four
10 = ten
12 = twelve
100 = one hundred
108 = one hundred eight
299 = two hundred ninety-nine
1000 = one thousand
1003 = one thousand three
2040 = two thousand fourty
45213 = fourty-five thousand two hundred thirteen
100000 = one hundred thousand
100005 = one hundred thousand five
100010 = one hundred thousand ten
202020 = two hundred two thousand twenty
202022 = two hundred two thousand twenty-two
999999 = nine hundred ninety-nine thousand nine hundred ninety-nine
1000000 = one million
1000001 = one million one
10000000 = ten million
10000007 = ten million seven
99999999 = ninety-nine million nine hundred ninety-nine thousand nine hundred ninety-nine
9223372036854775807 = nine quintillion two hundred twenty-three quadrillion three hundred seventy-two trillion thirty-six billion eight hundred fifty-four million seven hundred seventy-five thousand eight hundred seven
-9223372036854775808 = minus nine quintillion two hundred twenty-three quadrillion three hundred seventy-two trillion thirty-six billion eight hundred fifty-four million seven hundred seventy-five thousand eight hundred eight
0001.2 = one and two tenth
3.141592 = three and one hundred fourty-one thousand five hundred ninety-two millionth
694780458103427072928672912656674465845126458162617425283733729646.85695031739734695391404376 = six hundred ninety-four vigintillion seven hundred eighty novemdecillion four hundred fifty-eight octodecillion one hundred three septendecillion four hundred twenty-seven sexdecillion seventy-two quindecillion nine hundred twenty-eight quattuordecillion six hundred seventy-two tredecillion nine hundred twelve duodecillion six hundred fifty-six undecillion six hundred seventy-four decillion four hundred sixty-five nonillion eight hundred fourty-five octillion one hundred twenty-six septillion four hundred fifty-eight sextillion one hundred sixty-two quintillion six hundred seventeen quadrillion four hundred twenty-five trillion two hundred eighty-three billion seven hundred thirty-three million seven hundred twenty-nine thousand six hundred fourty-six and eighty-five septillion six hundred ninety-five sextillion thirty-one quintillion seven hundred thirty-nine quadrillion seven hundred thirty-four trillion six hundred ninety-five billion three hundred ninety-one million four hundred four thousand three hundred seventy-six hundred-septillionth
```

Comment: just need this for english alone

Comment: @Jason, I was answering the question "Is there an easy to use function in any of the math libraries which I can use for this purpose?"

Comment: American English or British English?  Billion has different meanings between these cultures.

Comment: @Don Roby - AFAIK, that is a historical concern only.  Most british folks use the american english meaning these days.  ( Of course, there are a few eccentrics around who write letters (in green ink) to The Times about this kind of thing, but they probably won't notice, on account of refusing to learn to use computers :-) )

Comment: @Rochon : Nice code !! Helped me a lot..but has a small bug..test with "10.00"...to remove this bug a want to add a little fix while converting string to word,                                                                                                                                  int indexOfDecimal = value.indexOf(".");
String decimal = value.substring(indexOfDecimal + 1, value.length());
BigDecimal decimalValue = new BigDecimal(decimal);
if (decimalValue.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0)
    value = value.substring(0, indexOfDecimal);

Comment: @AbhishekChatterjee, thanks! The idea of "good code" and "best practices" are to avoid putting redundant and unnecessary checks where they don't belong (to avoid code complexity); therefore providing the correct value should not be the concern of a class (or method) that format said value (format != validation). Moreover, the method `getName(string)` is a convenient way to provide a number that is otherwise too big to be passed directly by value (ie. using a `double`). The example does not provide invalid output as it is assumed that the values have properly been validated.

Comment: @AbhishekChatterjee, I should have perhaps changed the method signature to provide with `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` instead. That would've avoided the problem you are describing.

Comment: "Despite being related to the word "four" (4), 40 is spelled "forty", and not "fourty"." - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/40_(number))

Answer (score 30):

I think that this solution is not the best, since it works only for `int`, but i think it's great for a beginner.

```
public class NumberWordConverter {
    public static final String[] units = {
            "", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven",
            "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen",
            "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"
    };

    public static final String[] tens = {
            "",        // 0
            "",        // 1
            "twenty",  // 2
            "thirty",  // 3
            "forty",   // 4
            "fifty",   // 5
            "sixty",   // 6
            "seventy", // 7
            "eighty",  // 8
            "ninety"   // 9
    };

    public static String convert(final int n) {
        if (n < 0) {
            return "minus " + convert(-n);
        }

        if (n < 20) {
            return units[n];
        }

        if (n < 100) {
            return tens[n / 10] + ((n % 10 != 0) ? " " : "") + units[n % 10];
        }

        if (n < 1000) {
            return units[n / 100] + " hundred" + ((n % 100 != 0) ? " " : "") + convert(n % 100);
        }

        if (n < 1000000) {
            return convert(n / 1000) + " thousand" + ((n % 1000 != 0) ? " " : "") + convert(n % 1000);
        }

        if (n < 1000000000) {
            return convert(n / 1000000) + " million" + ((n % 1000000 != 0) ? " " : "") + convert(n % 1000000);
        }

        return convert(n / 1000000000) + " billion"  + ((n % 1000000000 != 0) ? " " : "") + convert(n % 1000000000);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Random generator = new Random();

        int n;
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            n = generator.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

            System.out.printf("%10d = '%s'%n", n, convert(n));
        }

        n = 1000;
        System.out.printf("%10d = '%s'%n", n, convert(n));

        n = 2000;
        System.out.printf("%10d = '%s'%n", n, convert(n));

        n = 10000;
        System.out.printf("%10d = '%s'%n", n, convert(n));

        n = 11000;
        System.out.printf("%10d = '%s'%n", n, convert(n));

        n = 999999999;
        System.out.printf("%10d = '%s'%n", n, convert(n));

        n = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        System.out.printf("%10d = '%s'%n", n, convert(n));
    }
}
```

The test creates 20 random numbers up to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and than some that know to be problematic, because of 0, 10, etc.. Output:

```
   5599908 = 'five million five hundred ninety nine thousand nine hundred eight'
 192603486 = 'one hundred ninety two million six hundred three thousand four hundred eighty six'
1392431868 = 'one billion three hundred ninety two million four hundred thirty one thousand eight hundred sixty eight'
1023787010 = 'one billion twenty three million seven hundred eighty seven thousand ten'
1364396236 = 'one billion three hundred sixty four million three hundred ninety six thousand two hundred thirty six'
1511255671 = 'one billion five hundred eleven million two hundred fifty five thousand six hundred seventy one'
 225955221 = 'two hundred twenty five million nine hundred fifty five thousand two hundred twenty one'
1890141052 = 'one billion eight hundred ninety million one hundred forty one thousand fifty two'
 261839422 = 'two hundred sixty one million eight hundred thirty nine thousand four hundred twenty two'
 728428650 = 'seven hundred twenty eight million four hundred twenty eight thousand six hundred fifty'
 860607319 = 'eight hundred sixty million six hundred seven thousand three hundred nineteen'
 719753587 = 'seven hundred nineteen million seven hundred fifty three thousand five hundred eighty seven'
2063829124 = 'two billion sixty three million eight hundred twenty nine thousand one hundred twenty four'
1081010996 = 'one billion eighty one million ten thousand nine hundred ninety six'
 999215799 = 'nine hundred ninety nine million two hundred fifteen thousand seven hundred ninety nine'
2105226236 = 'two billion one hundred five million two hundred twenty six thousand two hundred thirty six'
1431882940 = 'one billion four hundred thirty one million eight hundred eighty two thousand nine hundred forty'
1991707241 = 'one billion nine hundred ninety one million seven hundred seven thousand two hundred forty one'
1088301563 = 'one billion eighty eight million three hundred one thousand five hundred sixty three'
 964601609 = 'nine hundred sixty four million six hundred one thousand six hundred nine'
      1000 = 'one thousand'
      2000 = 'two thousand'
     10000 = 'ten thousand'
     11000 = 'eleven thousand'
 999999999 = 'nine hundred ninety nine million nine hundred ninety nine thousand nine hundred ninety nine'
2147483647 = 'two billion one hundred forty seven million four hundred eighty three thousand six hundred forty seven'
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Its way too good but what about for Indian number? We don't have millions and etc...

Answer (score 16):

```
package it.tommasoresti.facebook;

class NumbersToWords {

    private static final String ZERO = "zero";
    private static String[] oneToNine = {
            "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"
    };

    private static String[] tenToNinteen = {
            "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"
    };

    private static String[] dozens = {
            "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"
    };

    public static String solution(int number) {
        if(number == 0)
            return ZERO;

        return generate(number).trim();
    }

    public static String generate(int number) {
        if(number >= 1000000000) {
            return generate(number / 1000000000) + " billion " + generate(number % 1000000000);
        }
        else if(number >= 1000000) {
            return generate(number / 1000000) + " million " + generate(number % 1000000);
        }
        else if(number >= 1000) {
            return generate(number / 1000) + " thousand " + generate(number % 1000);
        }
        else if(number >= 100) {
            return generate(number / 100) + " hundred " + generate(number % 100);
        }

        return generate1To99(number);
    }

    private static String generate1To99(int number) {
        if (number == 0)
            return "";

        if (number <= 9)
            return oneToNine[number - 1];
        else if (number <= 19)
            return tenToNinteen[number % 10];
        else {
            return dozens[number / 10 - 1] + " " + generate1To99(number % 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Test

```
@Test
public void given_a_complex_number() throws Exception {
    assertThat(solution(1234567890),
        is("one billion two hundred thirty four million five hundred sixty seven thousand eight hundred ninety"));
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
/**

This Program will display the given number in words from 0 to 999999999

@author Manoj Kumar Dunna

Mail Id : manojdunna@gmail.com

**/  


import java.util.Scanner;

class NumberToString
{

    public enum hundreds {OneHundred, TwoHundred, ThreeHundred, FourHundred, FiveHundred, SixHundred, SevenHundred, EightHundred, NineHundred}
    public enum tens {Twenty, Thirty, Forty, Fifty, Sixty, Seventy, Eighty, Ninety}
    public enum ones {One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine}
    public enum denom {Thousand, Lakhs, Crores}
    public enum splNums { Ten, Eleven, Twelve, Thirteen, Fourteen, Fifteen, Sixteen, Seventeen, Eighteen, Nineteen}
    public static String text = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Number to convert into words");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        long num = sc.nextInt();
        int rem = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while(num > 0)
        {
            if(i == 0){
                rem = (int) (num % 1000);
                printText(rem);
                num = num / 1000;
                i++;
            }
            else if(num > 0)
            {
                rem = (int) (num % 100);
                if(rem > 0)
                    text = denom.values()[i - 1]+ " " + text;
                printText(rem);
                num = num / 100;
                i++;
            }
        }
        if(i > 0)
            System.out.println(text);
        else
            System.out.println("Zero");
    }

    public static void printText(int num)
    {
        if(!(num > 9 && num < 19))
        {
            if(num % 10 > 0)
                getOnes(num % 10);

            num = num / 10;
            if(num % 10 > 0)
                getTens(num % 10);

            num = num / 10;
            if(num > 0)
                getHundreds(num);
        }
        else
        {
            getSplNums(num % 10);
        }
    }

    public static void getSplNums(int num)
    {
        text = splNums.values()[num]+ " " + text;
    }

    public static void getHundreds(int num)
    {
        text = hundreds.values()[num - 1]+ " " + text;
    }

    public static void getTens(int num)
    {
        text = tens.values()[num - 2]+ " " + text;
    }

    public static void getOnes(int num)
    {
        text = ones.values()[num - 1]+ " " + text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Lakh and Crore is used Indian English but not in Europe and not in America. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh).

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [Tradukisto](https://github.com/allegro/tradukisto). It's a Java library I've written which does the job.

Comment: Is there a reason why all these answers have bad grammar? "one thousand two hundred thirty-four" should be "one thousand, two hundred **and** thirty-four". Is this some banking English I don't know about?

Comment: @weston In American English the "and" is not used. That's only in British English.

Comment: @4castle heh, American wife, I live in Canada and I never noticed!

Answer (score 4):

In this post i have just update ***Yanick Rochon's*** code. I have make it workable with lower version of java 1.6 and i was getting the output for **1.00 = one and  hundredth**. So i have update the code. New i get the output for ***1.00 = one and zero hundredth***.

I don't not what should i do. Add a new answer or edit that post. As the answer is highly ranked so i have made a new post with updating the code. I have just change this two things have mention above.

```
/**
 * This class will convert numeric values into an english representation
 * 
 * For units, see : http://www.jimloy.com/math/billion.htm
 * 
 * @author yanick.rochon@gmail.com
 */
public class NumberToWords {

    static public class ScaleUnit {
        private int exponent;
        private String[] names;

        private ScaleUnit(int exponent, String... names) {
            this.exponent = exponent;
            this.names = names;
        }

        public int getExponent() {
            return exponent;
        }

        public String getName(int index) {
            return names[index];
        }
    }

    /**
     * See http://www.wordiq.com/definition/Names_of_large_numbers
     */
    static private ScaleUnit[] SCALE_UNITS = new ScaleUnit[] {
            new ScaleUnit(63, "vigintillion", "decilliard"),
            new ScaleUnit(60, "novemdecillion", "decillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(57, "octodecillion", "nonilliard"),
            new ScaleUnit(54, "septendecillion", "nonillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(51, "sexdecillion", "octilliard"),
            new ScaleUnit(48, "quindecillion", "octillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(45, "quattuordecillion", "septilliard"),
            new ScaleUnit(42, "tredecillion", "septillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(39, "duodecillion", "sextilliard"),
            new ScaleUnit(36, "undecillion", "sextillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(33, "decillion", "quintilliard"),
            new ScaleUnit(30, "nonillion", "quintillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(27, "octillion", "quadrilliard"),
            new ScaleUnit(24, "septillion", "quadrillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(21, "sextillion", "trilliard"),
            new ScaleUnit(18, "quintillion", "trillion"),
            new ScaleUnit(15, "quadrillion", "billiard"),
            new ScaleUnit(12, "trillion", "billion"),
            new ScaleUnit(9, "billion", "milliard"),
            new ScaleUnit(6, "million", "million"),
            new ScaleUnit(3, "thousand", "thousand"),
            new ScaleUnit(2, "hundred", "hundred"),
            // new ScaleUnit(1, "ten", "ten"),
            // new ScaleUnit(0, "one", "one"),
            new ScaleUnit(-1, "tenth", "tenth"), new ScaleUnit(-2, "hundredth", "hundredth"),
            new ScaleUnit(-3, "thousandth", "thousandth"),
            new ScaleUnit(-4, "ten-thousandth", "ten-thousandth"),
            new ScaleUnit(-5, "hundred-thousandth", "hundred-thousandth"),
            new ScaleUnit(-6, "millionth", "millionth"),
            new ScaleUnit(-7, "ten-millionth", "ten-millionth"),
            new ScaleUnit(-8, "hundred-millionth", "hundred-millionth"),
            new ScaleUnit(-9, "billionth", "milliardth"),
            new ScaleUnit(-10, "ten-billionth", "ten-milliardth"),
            new ScaleUnit(-11, "hundred-billionth", "hundred-milliardth"),
            new ScaleUnit(-12, "trillionth", "billionth"),
            new ScaleUnit(-13, "ten-trillionth", "ten-billionth"),
            new ScaleUnit(-14, "hundred-trillionth", "hundred-billionth"),
            new ScaleUnit(-15, "quadrillionth", "billiardth"),
            new ScaleUnit(-16, "ten-quadrillionth", "ten-billiardth"),
            new ScaleUnit(-17, "hundred-quadrillionth", "hundred-billiardth"),
            new ScaleUnit(-18, "quintillionth", "trillionth"),
            new ScaleUnit(-19, "ten-quintillionth", "ten-trillionth"),
            new ScaleUnit(-20, "hundred-quintillionth", "hundred-trillionth"),
            new ScaleUnit(-21, "sextillionth", "trilliardth"),
            new ScaleUnit(-22, "ten-sextillionth", "ten-trilliardth"),
            new ScaleUnit(-23, "hundred-sextillionth", "hundred-trilliardth"),
            new ScaleUnit(-24, "septillionth", "quadrillionth"),
            new ScaleUnit(-25, "ten-septillionth", "ten-quadrillionth"),
            new ScaleUnit(-26, "hundred-septillionth", "hundred-quadrillionth"), };

    static public enum Scale {
        SHORT, LONG;

        public String getName(int exponent) {
            for (ScaleUnit unit : SCALE_UNITS) {
                if (unit.getExponent() == exponent) {
                    return unit.getName(this.ordinal());
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Change this scale to support American and modern British value (short scale) or Traditional
     * British value (long scale)
     */
    static public Scale SCALE = Scale.SHORT;

    static abstract public class AbstractProcessor {

        static protected final String SEPARATOR = " ";
        static protected final int NO_VALUE = -1;

        protected List<Integer> getDigits(long value) {
            ArrayList<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            if (value == 0) {
                digits.add(0);
            } else {
                while (value > 0) {
                    digits.add(0, (int) value % 10);
                    value /= 10;
                }
            }
            return digits;
        }

        public String getName(long value) {
            return getName(Long.toString(value));
        }

        public String getName(double value) {
            return getName(Double.toString(value));
        }

        abstract public String getName(String value);
    }

    static public class UnitProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

        static private final String[] TOKENS = new String[] { "one", "two", "three", "four",
                "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen",
                "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen" };

        @Override
        public String getName(String value) {
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

            int offset = NO_VALUE;
            int number;
            if (value.length() > 3) {
                number = Integer.valueOf(value.substring(value.length() - 3), 10);
            } else {
                number = Integer.valueOf(value, 10);
            }
            number %= 100;
            if (number < 10) {
                offset = (number % 10) - 1;
                // number /= 10;
            } else if (number < 20) {
                offset = (number % 20) - 1;
                // number /= 100;
            }

            if (offset != NO_VALUE && offset < TOKENS.length) {
                buffer.append(TOKENS[offset]);
            }

            return buffer.toString();
        }

    }

    static public class TensProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

        static private final String[] TOKENS = new String[] { "twenty", "thirty", "fourty",
                "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety" };

        static private final String UNION_SEPARATOR = "-";

        private UnitProcessor unitProcessor = new UnitProcessor();

        @Override
        public String getName(String value) {
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            boolean tensFound = false;

            int number;
            if (value.length() > 3) {
                number = Integer.valueOf(value.substring(value.length() - 3), 10);
            } else {
                number = Integer.valueOf(value, 10);
            }
            number %= 100; // keep only two digits
            if (number >= 20) {
                buffer.append(TOKENS[(number / 10) - 2]);
                number %= 10;
                tensFound = true;
            } else {
                number %= 20;
            }

            if (number != 0) {
                if (tensFound) {
                    buffer.append(UNION_SEPARATOR);
                }
                buffer.append(unitProcessor.getName(number));
            }

            return buffer.toString();
        }
    }

    static public class HundredProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

        private int EXPONENT = 2;

        private UnitProcessor unitProcessor = new UnitProcessor();
        private TensProcessor tensProcessor = new TensProcessor();

        @Override
        public String getName(String value) {
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

            int number;
            if ("".equals(value)) {
                number = 0;
            } else if (value.length() > 4) {
                number = Integer.valueOf(value.substring(value.length() - 4), 10);
            } else {
                number = Integer.valueOf(value, 10);
            }
            number %= 1000; // keep at least three digits

            if (number >= 100) {
                buffer.append(unitProcessor.getName(number / 100));
                buffer.append(SEPARATOR);
                buffer.append(SCALE.getName(EXPONENT));
            }

            String tensName = tensProcessor.getName(number % 100);

            if (!"".equals(tensName) && (number >= 100)) {
                buffer.append(SEPARATOR);
            }
            buffer.append(tensName);

            return buffer.toString();
        }
    }

    static public class CompositeBigProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

        private HundredProcessor hundredProcessor = new HundredProcessor();
        private AbstractProcessor lowProcessor;
        private int exponent;

        public CompositeBigProcessor(int exponent) {
            if (exponent <= 3) {
                lowProcessor = hundredProcessor;
            } else {
                lowProcessor = new CompositeBigProcessor(exponent - 3);
            }
            this.exponent = exponent;
        }

        public String getToken() {
            return SCALE.getName(getPartDivider());
        }

        protected AbstractProcessor getHighProcessor() {
            return hundredProcessor;
        }

        protected AbstractProcessor getLowProcessor() {
            return lowProcessor;
        }

        public int getPartDivider() {
            return exponent;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName(String value) {
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

            String high, low;
            if (value.length() < getPartDivider()) {
                high = "";
                low = value;
            } else {
                int index = value.length() - getPartDivider();
                high = value.substring(0, index);
                low = value.substring(index);
            }

            String highName = getHighProcessor().getName(high);
            String lowName = getLowProcessor().getName(low);

            if (!"".equals(highName)) {
                buffer.append(highName);
                buffer.append(SEPARATOR);
                buffer.append(getToken());

                if (!"".equals(lowName)) {
                    buffer.append(SEPARATOR);
                }
            }

            if (!"".equals(lowName)) {
                buffer.append(lowName);
            }

            return buffer.toString();
        }
    }

    static public class DefaultProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

        static private String MINUS = "minus";
        static private String UNION_AND = "and";

        static private String ZERO_TOKEN = "zero";

        private AbstractProcessor processor = new CompositeBigProcessor(63);

        @Override
        public String getName(String value) {
            boolean negative = false;
            if (value.startsWith("-")) {
                negative = true;
                value = value.substring(1);
            }

            int decimals = value.indexOf(".");
            String decimalValue = null;
            if (0 <= decimals) {
                decimalValue = value.substring(decimals + 1);
                value = value.substring(0, decimals);
            }

            String name = processor.getName(value);

            if ("".equals(name)) {
                name = ZERO_TOKEN;
            } else if (negative) {
                name = MINUS.concat(SEPARATOR).concat(name);
            }

            if (!(null == decimalValue || "".equals(decimalValue))) {

                String zeroDecimalValue = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < decimalValue.length(); i++) {
                    zeroDecimalValue = zeroDecimalValue + "0";
                }
                if (decimalValue.equals(zeroDecimalValue)) {
                    name = name.concat(SEPARATOR).concat(UNION_AND).concat(SEPARATOR).concat(
                            "zero").concat(SEPARATOR).concat(
                            SCALE.getName(-decimalValue.length()));
                } else {
                    name = name.concat(SEPARATOR).concat(UNION_AND).concat(SEPARATOR).concat(
                            processor.getName(decimalValue)).concat(SEPARATOR).concat(
                            SCALE.getName(-decimalValue.length()));
                }

            }

            return name;
        }

    }

    static public AbstractProcessor processor;

    public static void main(String... args) {

        processor = new DefaultProcessor();

        long[] values = new long[] { 0, 4, 10, 12, 100, 108, 299, 1000, 1003, 2040, 45213, 100000,
                100005, 100010, 202020, 202022, 999999, 1000000, 1000001, 10000000, 10000007,
                99999999, Long.MAX_VALUE, Long.MIN_VALUE };

        String[] strValues = new String[] { "0", "1.30", "0001.00", "3.141592" };

        for (long val : values) {
            System.out.println(val + " = " + processor.getName(val));
        }

        for (String strVal : strValues) {
            System.out.println(strVal + " = " + processor.getName(strVal));
        }

        // generate a very big number...
        StringBuilder bigNumber = new StringBuilder();
        for (int d = 0; d < 66; d++) {
            bigNumber.append((char) ((Math.random() * 10) + '0'));
        }
        bigNumber.append(".");
        for (int d = 0; d < 26; d++) {
            bigNumber.append((char) ((Math.random() * 10) + '0'));
        }
        System.out.println(bigNumber.toString() + " = " + processor.getName(bigNumber.toString()));
    }
}
```

The output is

```
0 = zero
4 = four
10 = ten
12 = twelve
100 = one hundred
108 = one hundred eight
299 = two hundred ninety-nine
1000 = one thousand
1003 = one thousand three
2040 = two thousand fourty
45213 = fourty-five thousand two hundred thirteen
100000 = one hundred thousand
100005 = one hundred thousand five
100010 = one hundred thousand ten
202020 = two hundred two thousand twenty
202022 = two hundred two thousand twenty-two
999999 = nine hundred ninety-nine thousand nine hundred ninety-nine
1000000 = one million
1000001 = one million one
10000000 = ten million
10000007 = ten million seven
99999999 = ninety-nine million nine hundred ninety-nine thousand nine hundred ninety-nine
9223372036854775807 = nine quintillion two hundred twenty-three quadrillion three hundred seventy-two trillion thirty-six billion eight hundred fifty-four million seven hundred seventy-five thousand eight hundred seven
-9223372036854775808 = minus nine quintillion two hundred twenty-three quadrillion three hundred seventy-two trillion thirty-six billion eight hundred fifty-four million seven hundred seventy-five thousand eight hundred eight
0.0 = zero and zero tenth
1.30 = one and thirty hundredth
0001.00 = one and zero hundredth
3.141592 = three and one hundred fourty-one thousand five hundred ninety-two millionth
354064188376576616844741830273568537829518115677552666352927559274.76892492652888527014418647 = three hundred fifty-four vigintillion sixty-four novemdecillion one hundred eighty-eight octodecillion three hundred seventy-six septendecillion five hundred seventy-six sexdecillion six hundred sixteen quindecillion eight hundred fourty-four quattuordecillion seven hundred fourty-one tredecillion eight hundred thirty duodecillion two hundred seventy-three undecillion five hundred sixty-eight decillion five hundred thirty-seven nonillion eight hundred twenty-nine octillion five hundred eighteen septillion one hundred fifteen sextillion six hundred seventy-seven quintillion five hundred fifty-two quadrillion six hundred sixty-six trillion three hundred fifty-two billion nine hundred twenty-seven million five hundred fifty-nine thousand two hundred seventy-four and seventy-six septillion eight hundred ninety-two sextillion four hundred ninety-two quintillion six hundred fifty-two quadrillion eight hundred eighty-eight trillion five hundred twenty-seven billion fourteen million four hundred eighteen thousand six hundred fourty-seven hundred-septillionth
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ICU4J](http://site.icu-project.org), Just need to add POM entry and code is below for any Number, Country and Language.

POM Entry

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
        <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
        <version>64.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Code is

```
public class TranslateNumberToWord {

/**
 * Translate
 * 
 * @param ctryCd
 * @param lang
 * @param reqStr
 * @param fractionUnitName
 * @return
 */
public static String translate(String ctryCd, String lang, String reqStr, String fractionUnitName) {
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

    Locale locale = new Locale(lang, ctryCd);
    Currency crncy = Currency.getInstance(locale);

    String inputArr[] = StringUtils.split(new BigDecimal(reqStr).abs().toPlainString(), ".");
    RuleBasedNumberFormat rule = new RuleBasedNumberFormat(locale, RuleBasedNumberFormat.SPELLOUT);

    int i = 0;
    for (String input : inputArr) {
        CurrencyAmount crncyAmt = new CurrencyAmount(new BigDecimal(input), crncy);
        if (i++ == 0) {
            result.append(rule.format(crncyAmt)).append(" " + crncy.getDisplayName() + " and ");
        } else {
            result.append(rule.format(crncyAmt)).append(" " + fractionUnitName + " ");
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String ctryCd = "US";
    String lang = "en";
    String input = "95.17";

    String result = translate(ctryCd, lang, input, "Cents");
    System.out.println("Input: " + input + " result: " + result);
}}
```

Tested with quite a big number and output would be

```
Input: 95.17 result: ninety-five US Dollar and seventeen Cents
Input: 999999999999999999.99 result: nine hundred ninety-nine quadrillion nine hundred ninety-nine trillion nine hundred ninety-nine billion nine hundred ninety-nine million nine hundred ninety-nine thousand nine hundred ninety-nine US Dollar and ninety-nine Cents
```

Answer (score 3):

```
/* this program will display number in words
for eg. if you enter 101,it will show "ONE HUNDRED AND ONE"*/

import java.util.*;

public class NumToWords {
  String string;
  String st1[] = { "", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven",
                   "eight", "nine", };
  String st2[] = { "hundred", "thousand", "lakh", "crore" };
  String st3[] = { "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen",
                   "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "ninteen", };
  String st4[] = { "twenty", "thirty", "fourty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy",
                   "eighty", "ninety" };

  public String convert(int number) {
    int n = 1;
    int word;
    string = "";
    while (number != 0) {
      switch (n) {
        case 1:
          word = number % 100;
          pass(word);
          if (number > 100 && number % 100 != 0) {
            show("and ");
            //System.out.print("ankit");
          }
          number /= 100;
          break;
        case 2:
          word = number % 10;
          if (word != 0) {
            show(" ");
            show(st2[0]);
            show(" ");
            pass(word);
          }
          number /= 10;
          break;
        case 3:
          word = number % 100;
          if (word != 0) {
            show(" ");
            show(st2[1]);
            show(" ");
            pass(word);
          }
          number /= 100;
          break;
        case 4:
          word = number % 100;
          if (word != 0) {
            show(" ");
            show(st2[2]);
            show(" ");
            pass(word);
          }
          number /= 100;
          break;
        case 5:
          word = number % 100;
          if (word != 0) {
            show(" ");
            show(st2[3]);
            show(" ");
            pass(word);
          }
          number /= 100;
          break;
        }
        n++;
      }
      return string;
    }

  public void pass(int number) {
    int word, q;
    if (number < 10) {
      show(st1[number]);
    }
    if (number > 9 && number < 20) {
      show(st3[number - 10]);
    }
    if (number > 19) {
      word = number % 10;
      if (word == 0) {
        q = number / 10;
        show(st4[q - 2]);
      } else {
        q = number / 10;
        show(st1[word]);
        show(" ");
        show(st4[q - 2]);
      }
    }
  }

  public void show(String s) {
    String st;
    st = string;
    string = s;
    string += st;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    NumToWords w = new NumToWords();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Number: ");
    int num = input.nextInt();
    String inwords = w.convert(num);
    System.out.println(inwords);
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to add some description along with code... Welcome to [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 3):

I think this may help you...programme is very simple and works fine

```
import java.util.*;

public class NumberToWord

{
    public void pw(int n, String ch)
    {
        String one[] = {

        " ", " one", " two", " three", " four", " five", " six", " seven",
                " eight", " Nine", " ten", " eleven", " twelve", " thirteen",
                " fourteen", "fifteen", " sixteen", " seventeen", " eighteen",
                " nineteen" };
        String ten[] = { " ", " ", " twenty", " thirty", " forty", " fifty",
                " sixty", "seventy", " eighty", " ninety" };
        if (n > 19) {
            System.out.print(ten[n / 10] + " " + one[n % 10]);
        } else {
            System.out.print(one[n]);
        }
        if (n > 0)
            System.out.print(ch);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        int n = 0;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an integer number: ");
        n = s.nextInt();
        if (n <= 0)
            System.out.print("Enter numbers greater than 0");
        else
        {
            NumberToWord a = new NumberToWord();
            System.out.print("After conversion number in words is :");
            a.pw((n / 1000000000), " Hundred");
            a.pw((n / 10000000) % 100, " crore");
            a.pw(((n / 100000) % 100), " lakh");
            a.pw(((n / 1000) % 100), " thousand");
            a.pw(((n / 100) % 10), " hundred");
            a.pw((n % 100), " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very simple class [NumberInWords.java](https://github.com/busaeed/Integer-To-Words-Java/blob/master/NumberInWords.java) that can have the job done very easily:

```
String numberInWords = NumberInWords.convertNumberToWords(27546); //twenty seven thousand and five hundred forty six
```

It's important to know that this class is **only** capable of converting int datatype.

Answer (score 2):

You can use RuleBasedNumberFormat. for example result will give you `Ninety`

```
ULocale locale = new ULocale(Locale.US);  //us english
Double d = Double.parseDouble(90);
NumberFormat formatter = new RuleBasedNumberFormat(locale, RuleBasedNumberFormat.SPELLOUT);
String result = formatter.format(d);
```

It supports a wide range of languages.

Comment: For spanish speakers I suggesting read this answer too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10019105/3954514

Answer (score 1):

I've developed a Java component to convert given number into words. All you've to do is - just copy the whole class from <s>[Java program to convert numbers to words](http://www.javaservletsjspweb.in/2009/05/java-class-to-convert-number-into-words.html)</s> and paste it in your project.

Just invoke it like below

```
Words w = Words.getInstance(1234567);
System.out.println(w.getNumberInWords());
```

My program supports up to 10 million. If you want, you can still extend this. Just below the example output

```
2345223 = Twenty Three Lakh Fourty Five Thousand Two Hundred Twenty Three
9999999 = Ninety Nine Lakh Ninety Nine Thousand Nine Hundred Ninety Nine
199 = One Hundred Ninety Nine
10 = Ten
```

Thanks

Santhosh

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need this any more, but I recently wrote a java class to do this. Apparently Yanick Rochon did something similar. It will convert numbers up to 999 Novemdecillion (999*10^60). It could do more if I knew what came after Novemdecillion, but I would be willing to bet it's unnecessary. Just feed the number as a string in cents. The output is also grammatically correct.

[Here is a link to the Bitbucket Repo](https://bitbucket.org/smleimberg/moneytowords)

Comment: FYI, this link seems to be broken

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;

public class NumberToWord {
    public void numberToword(int n, String ch) {
        String one[] = {" ", " one", " two", " three", " four", " five", " six", " seven", " eight", " Nine", " ten", " eleven", " twelve", " thirteen", " fourteen", "fifteen", " sixteen", " seventeen", " eighteen", " nineteen"
        };
        String ten[] = {" ", " ", " twenty", " thirty", " forty", " fifty", " sixty", "seventy", " eighty", " ninety"};
        if (n > 19) {
            System.out.print(ten[n / 10] + " " + one[n % 10]);
        } else {
            System.out.print(one[n]);
        }
        if (n > 0) {
            System.out.print(ch);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 0;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an integer number: ");
        n = s.nextInt();
        if (n <= 0) {
            System.out.print("Enter numbers greater than 0");
        } else {
            NumberToWord a = new NumberToWord();
            System.out.print("After conversion number in words is :");
            a.numberToword((n / 1000000000), " Hundred");
            a.numberToword((n / 10000000) % 100, " crore");
            a.numberToword(((n / 100000) % 100), " lakh");
            a.numberToword(((n / 1000) % 100), " thousand");
            a.numberToword(((n / 100) % 10), " hundred");
            a.numberToword((n % 100), " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this might help

```
public String numberToWords(long number) {
    if (number == 0) {
        return "zero";
    }
    if (number < 0) {
        return "minus " + numberToWords(Math.abs(number));
    }
    String words = "";
    if ((number / 10000000) > 0) {
        words += numberToWords(number / 10000000) + " Crore ";
        number %= 10000000;
    }
    if ((number / 100000) > 0) {
        words += numberToWords(number / 100000) + " Lakh ";
        number %= 100000;
    }
    if ((number / 1000) > 0) {
        words += numberToWords(number / 1000) + " Thousand ";
        number %= 1000;
    }
    if ((number / 100) > 0) {
        words += numberToWords(number / 100) + " Hundred ";
        number %= 100;
    }
    if (number > 0) {
        if (!words.equals("")) {
            words += "and ";
        }
        if (number < 20) {
            words += number;
        } else {
            words += (number);
            if ((number % 10) > 0) {
                words += "-" + (number % 10);
            }
        }
    }
    return words;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The same accepted answer (Jigar Joshi), but now in Spanish. Feel free to change this if you find a mistake. Easier than french, but based on that though....

**Spanish:**

```
import java.text.*;

class SpanishNumberToWords {
  private static final String[] tensNames = {
    "",
    "",
    "veinte",
    "treinta",
    "cuarenta",
    "cincuenta",
    "sesenta",
    "setenta",
    "ochenta",
    "noventa"
  };

  private static final String[] unitNames1 = {
    "",
    "un",
    "dos",
    "tres",
    "cuatro",
    "cinco",
    "seis",
    "siete",
    "ocho",
    "nueve",
    "diez",
    "once",
    "doce",
    "trece",
    "catorce",
    "quince",
    "dieciseis",
    "diecisiete",
    "dieciocho",
    "diecinueve",
    "veinte",
    "veintiun",
    "veintidos",
    "veintitres",
    "veinticuatro",
    "veinticinco",
    "veintiseis",
    "veintisiete",
    "veintiocho",
    "veintinueve",
  };

  private static final String[] unitNames2 = {
    "",
    "",
    "dosc",
    "tresc",
    "cuatroc",
    "quin",
    "seisc",
    "setec",
    "ochoc",
    "novec",
    "diez"
  };

  private SpanishNumberToWords() {}

  private static String convertZeroToHundred(int number) {

    int theTens = number / 10;
    int theUnit = number % 10;
    String result = "";

    // separator
    String theSeparator = "";
    if (theTens > 1) {
        theSeparator = " y ";
    }
    // particular cases
    switch (theUnit) {
    case 0:
        theSeparator = "";
      break;
    default:
    }

    // tens in letters
    switch (theTens) {
    case 0:
        result = unitNames1[theUnit];
      break;
    case 1: case 2:
        result =  unitNames1[theTens*10+theUnit];
        break;
    default :
        result = tensNames[theTens]
                              + theSeparator + unitNames1[theUnit];
    }
    return result;
  }

  private static String convertLessThanOneThousand(int number) {

    int theHundreds = number / 100;
    int leReste = number % 100;
    String sReste = convertZeroToHundred(leReste);

    String result;
    switch (theHundreds) {
    case 0:
        result = sReste;
      break;
    case 1 :
      if (leReste > 0) {
          result = "ciento " + sReste;
      }
      else {
          result = "cien";
      }
      break;
    default :
      if (leReste > 0) {
          result = unitNames2[theHundreds] + "ientos " + sReste;
      }
      else {
          result = unitNames2[theHundreds] + "ientos";
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  public static String convert(long number) {
    // 0 à 999 999 999 999
    if (number == 0) { return "cero"; }

    String snumber = Long.toString(number);

    // pad des "0"
    String mask = "000000000000";
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(mask);
    snumber = df.format(number);

    // XXXnnnnnnnnn
    int theMilliards = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(0,3));
    // nnnXXXnnnnnn
    int theMillions  = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(3,6));
    // nnnnnnXXXnnn
    int theCentMiles = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(6,9));
    // nnnnnnnnnXXX
    int lesMille = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(9,12));

    String tradMilliards;
    switch (theMilliards) {
    case 0:
      tradMilliards = "";
      break;
    case 1 :
      tradMilliards = convertLessThanOneThousand(theMilliards)
         + " mil millones ";
      break;
    default :
      tradMilliards = convertLessThanOneThousand(theMilliards)
         + " mil millones ";
    }
    String resultat =  tradMilliards;

    String tradMillions;
    switch (theMillions) {
    case 0:
      tradMillions = "";
      break;
    case 1 :
      tradMillions = convertLessThanOneThousand(theMillions)
         + " millon ";
      break;
    default :
      tradMillions = convertLessThanOneThousand(theMillions)
         + " millones ";
    }
    resultat =  resultat + tradMillions;

    String tradCentMille;
    switch (theCentMiles) {
    case 0:
      tradCentMille = "";
      break;
    case 1 :
      tradCentMille = "mil ";
      break;
    default :
      tradCentMille = convertLessThanOneThousand(theCentMiles)
         + " mil ";
    }
    resultat =  resultat + tradCentMille;

    String tradMille;
    tradMille = convertLessThanOneThousand(lesMille);
    resultat =  resultat + tradMille;

    return resultat;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(0));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(1));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(2));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(3));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(4));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(5));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(7));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(12));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(16));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(19));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(21));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(24));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(28));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(29));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(30));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(31));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(42));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(71));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(72));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(80));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(81));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(89));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(90));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(91));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(97));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(100));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(101));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(110));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(120));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(200));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(201));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(232));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(999));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(521));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(912));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(999));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(1000));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(1001));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(10000));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(10001));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(100000));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(267578));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(3000000000L));
    System.out.println("*** " + SpanishNumberToWords.convert(2147483647));
    /*
     *** OUTPUT
        *** cero
        *** un
        *** dos
        *** tres
        *** cuatro
        *** cinco
        *** siete
        *** doce
        *** dieciseis
        *** diecinueve
        *** veintiun
        *** veinticuatro
        *** veintiocho
        *** veintinueve
        *** treinta
        *** treinta y un
        *** cuarenta y dos
        *** setenta y un
        *** setenta y dos
        *** ochenta
        *** ochenta y un
        *** ochenta y nueve
        *** noventa
        *** noventa y un
        *** noventa y siete
        *** cien
        *** ciento un
        *** ciento diez
        *** ciento veinte
        *** doscientos
        *** doscientos un
        *** doscientos treinta y dos
        *** novecientos noventa y nueve
        *** quinientos veintiun
        *** novecientos doce
        *** novecientos noventa y nueve
        *** mil 
        *** mil un
        *** diez mil 
        *** diez mil un
        *** cien mil 
        *** doscientos sesenta y siete mil quinientos setenta y ocho
        *** tres mil millones 
        *** dos mil millones ciento cuarenta y siete millones cuatrocientos ochenta y tres mil seiscientos cuarenta y siete
     */
  }
```

Comment: You can also use ICUJ, I put an example here https://gist.github.com/earth001/bf30be16489e1c2538ac3dd55d9ffc94

Answer (score 1):

```
class NumberToWord {
    private static Map<Integer, String> numbers = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    private static Set<Integer> numberSet = new TreeSet<Integer>(new Comparator<Integer>() {
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return o2 - o1;
        }
    });

    static {
        init();
        numberSet.addAll(numbers.keySet());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getNumberInWord(1898765));
    }

    /*
     * convert positive numbers in word format number > 0 only
     */
    static String getNumberInWord(int number) {
        StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();
        for (Integer n : numberSet) {
            if (number > 0 && number >= n) {
                int div = number / n;
                String strNum = numbers.get(div);
                if (strNum == null) {
                    word.append(getNumberInWord(div));
                }
                // for less than 100, we don't need to say 1
                if (strNum != null && (div > 1 || n > 100))
                    word.append(strNum + " ");

                word.append(numbers.get(n) + " ");
                number = number % n;
            }
        }
        return word.toString();
    }

    static void init() {
        numbers.put(0, "Zero");
        numbers.put(1, "One");
        numbers.put(2, "Two");
        numbers.put(3, "Three");
        numbers.put(4, "Four");
        numbers.put(5, "Five");
        numbers.put(6, "Six");
        numbers.put(7, "Seven");
        numbers.put(8, "Eight");
        numbers.put(9, "Nine");
        numbers.put(10, "Ten");
        numbers.put(11, "Eleven");
        numbers.put(12, "Twelve");
        numbers.put(13, "Thirteen");
        numbers.put(14, "Fourteen");
        numbers.put(15, "Fifteen");
        numbers.put(16, "Sixteen");
        numbers.put(17, "Seventeen");
        numbers.put(18, "Eighteeen");
        numbers.put(19, "Nineteen");
        numbers.put(20, "Twenty");
        numbers.put(30, "Thirty");
        numbers.put(40, "Forty");
        numbers.put(50, "Fifty");
        numbers.put(60, "Sixty");
        numbers.put(70, "Seventy");
        numbers.put(80, "Eighty");
        numbers.put(90, "Ninty");
        numbers.put(100, "Hundred");
        numbers.put(1000, "Thousand");
        numbers.put(1000000, "Million");
        numbers.put(100000000, "Billion");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Intuitive solution

1: Build a sorted matrix of **[value - word]** type

2: Find the closest value from matrix for which **n/value > 0** (can use binary_search)

3: Recursively build the **left** and the **right** part of the number.

Your answer is **left_part** + **word** + **right_part**

```java
class Solution {
    private final Object[][] pairs = {
            {1000_000_000, "Billion"}, {100_00_00, "Million"}, {1000, "Thousand"}, {100, "Hundred"},
            {90, "Ninety"}, {80, "Eighty"}, {70, "Seventy"}, {60, "Sixty"},
            {50, "Fifty"}, {40, "Forty"}, {30, "Thirty"}, {20, "Twenty"},
            {19, "Nineteen"}, {18, "Eighteen"}, {17, "Seventeen"}, {16, "Sixteen"},
            {15, "Fifteen"}, {14, "Fourteen"}, {13, "Thirteen"}, {12, "Twelve"},
            {11, "Eleven"}, {10, "Ten"}, {9, "Nine"}, {8, "Eight"},
            {7, "Seven"}, {6, "Six"}, {5, "Five"}, {4, "Four"},
            {3, "Three"}, {2, "Two"}, {1, "One"}
    };

    private Object[] getPair(int num) {
        int n = pairs.length;
        int l = 0, r = n - 1;
        int result = -1;
        while (l <= r) {
            int mid = (l + r) >>> 1;
            int value = (Integer) pairs[mid][0];
            if (value == num) {
                return pairs[mid];
            }
            else if (num / value > 0) {
                result = mid;
                r = mid - 1;
            }
            else {
                l = mid + 1;
            }
        }
        return pairs[result];
    }

    public String numberToWords(int num) {
        if (num == 0) {
            return "Zero";
        }
        var pair = getPair(num);
        String word = (String) pair[1];
        int value = (Integer) pair[0];
        var left = num >= 100 ? numberToWords(num / value) + " " : "";
        var right = num % value == 0 ? "" : " " + numberToWords(num % value);
        return left + word + right;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it like this

```
package com.stack.overflow.number.in.english;

import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class ActualImplementation {

    public static ResourceBundle readPropertyFile = ResourceBundle
            .getBundle("NumberEnglishRepresentation");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ActualImplementation.main(-2));
    }

    public static String main(Integer number) {
        int power;
        // Calculate Number of digits

        Integer numberOfDigits = number > 0 ? (int) Math.log10((double) number) + 1
                : 1;
        String output = "";
        // If number is negative convert it to positive an append minus to
        // output
        if (Integer.signum(number) == -1) {
            output = "minus ";
            number = number < 0 ? number * -1 : number;
        }
        String stringVal = String.valueOf(number);

        if (number <= 20 || number == 30 || number == 40 || number == 50
                || number == 60 || number == 70 || number == 80 || number == 90
                || number == 100 || number == 1000)
            output += readPropertyFile.getString(stringVal);

        else {
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < numberOfDigits; i++) {

                if (number != 0) {

                    numberOfDigits = number > 0 ? (int) Math
                            .log10((double) number) + 1 : 1;

                    power = (int) Math.pow(10, numberOfDigits - 1);
                    // If number is like 10,001 then print ten first and then
                    // remaining value
                    if (numberOfDigits >= 5 && numberOfDigits % 2 == 1) {
                        power = (int) Math.pow(10, numberOfDigits - 2);
                    }

                    if (readPropertyFile.containsKey(String.valueOf(number)))
                        output += readPropertyFile.getString(String
                                .valueOf(number));
                    else {
                        // As the digits at units and tens place are read
                        // differently
                        if (numberOfDigits > 2) {

                            output += readPropertyFile.getString(String
                                    .valueOf(number / power))
                                    + readPropertyFile.getString(String
                                            .valueOf(power));
                        } else {
                            output += readPropertyFile.getString(String
                                    .valueOf(number - number % power));

                        }
                    }
                    number = (int) (number % power);

                }
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

and the resource file is :

```
0=zero
1=one
2=two
3=three
4=four
5=five
6=six
7=seven
8=eight
9=nine
10=ten 


11=eleven
12=twelve
13=thirteen
14=fourteen
15fifteen
16=sixteen
17=seventeen
18=eighteen
19=nineteen
20=twenty

30=thirty
40=fourty
50=fifty
60=sixty
70=seventy
80=eighty
90=ninety

100=hundred
1000=thousand
100000=Lakh
```

This one is implemented till 10 lakhs only

Answer (score 0):

```
public class NumberConverter {

    private String[] singleDigit = {"", " one", " two", " three",
    " four", " five"," six", " seven", " eight", " nine"};

    private String[] tens = {" ten", " eleven", " twelve", " thirteen",
            " fourteen", " fifteen"," sixteen", " seventeen", " eighteen", " nineteen"};

    private String[] twoDigits = {"", "", " twenty", " thirty",
            " forty", " fifty"," sixty", " seventy", " eighty", " ninety"};

    public String convertToWords(String input) {
        long number = Long.parseLong(input);
        int size = input.length();
        if (size <= 3) {
            int num = (int) number;
            return handle3Digits(num);
        } else if (size > 3 && size <= 6) {
            int thousand = (int)(number/1000);
            int hundred = (int) (number % 1000);
            String thousands = handle3Digits(thousand);

            String hundreds = handle3Digits(hundred);
            String word = "";

            if (!thousands.isEmpty()) {
                word = thousands +" thousand";
            }
            word += hundreds;
            return word;
        } else if (size > 6 && size <= 9) {
            int million = (int) (number/ 1000000);
            number = number % 1000000;
            int thousand = (int)(number/1000);
            int hundred = (int) (number % 1000);

            String millions = handle3Digits(million);
            String thousands = handle3Digits(thousand);
            String hundreds = handle3Digits(hundred);

            String word = "";

            if (!millions.isEmpty()) {
                word = millions +" million";
            }
            if (!thousands.isEmpty()) {
                word += thousands +" thousand";
            }
            word += hundreds;
            return word;
        }

        return "Not implemented yet.";
    }


    private String handle3Digits(int number) {
        if (number <= 0)
            return "";

        String word = "";
        if (number/100 > 0) {
            int dividend = number/100;
            word = singleDigit[dividend] + " hundred";
            number = number % 100;
        }
        if (number/10 > 1) {
            int dividend = number/10;
            number = number % 10;
            word += twoDigits[dividend];
        } else if (number/10 == 1) {
            number = number % 10;
            word += tens[number];
            return word;
        } else {
            number = number % 10;
        }
        if (number > 0) {
            word += singleDigit[number];
        }

        return word;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This program can convert up to 102 digits long number. Suggestions and comments are highly appreciated.

```
package com.kegeesoft;
/**
 * @author Chandana Gamage +94 710 980 120
 * @author maheshgamage375@gmail.com
 * @author KeGee Software Solutions
 */
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Converter {
    private final BigInteger zero = new BigInteger("0");        
    private final BigInteger scale[] = new BigInteger[33];                                        
    private final String scaleName[] = {" Duotrigintillion"," Untrigintillion"," Trigintillion",
                                        " Nonvigintillion"," Octovigintillion"," Septvigintillion",
                                        " Sexvigintillion"," Quinvigintillion"," Quattuorvigintillion",
                                        " Trevigintillion"," Duovigintillion"," Unvigintillion",
                                        " Vigintillion"," Novemdecillion"," Octodecillion",
                                        " Septemdecillion"," Sexdecillion"," Quindecillion",
                                        " Quattuordecillion "," Tredecillion"," Duodecillion",
                                        " Undecillion"," Decillion"," Nonillion"," Octillion",
                                        " Septillion"," Sextillion"," Quintillion"," Quadrillion",
                                        " Trillion"," Billion"," Million"," Thousand"};
    private final String ones[] = {""," One"," Two"," Three"," Four"," Five"," Six"," Seven"," Eight"," Nine",
                                   " Ten"," Eleven"," Twelve"," Thirteen"," Fourteen"," Fifteen"," Sixteen",
                                   " Seventeen"," Eighteen"," Nineteen"};    
    private final String tens[] = {"",""," Twenty"," Thirty"," Forty"," Fifty"," Sixty"," Seventy"," Eighty"," Ninety"};
    private int index = 0;    
    private String shortValueInWords = "";
    private String output = "";
    private String decimalInWords = "";
    private String valueInWords;

    public String setValue(BigInteger value) throws Exception{
        return this.bigValueInWords(value);
    }

    public String setValue(BigDecimal value) throws Exception{
        int indexOfDecimalPoint = (value.toString()).indexOf(".");

        // Split and pass interger value of given decimal value to constructor
        String tempIntValue = (value.toString()).substring(0, indexOfDecimalPoint);
        BigInteger intValue = new BigInteger(tempIntValue);

        // Split and pass decimal value of given decimal value to constructor
        String tempDeciValue = (value.toString()).substring(indexOfDecimalPoint+1, value.toString().length());
        BigInteger deciValue = new BigInteger(tempDeciValue);

        this.bigValueInWords(intValue);
        this.decimalValueInWords(deciValue);
        return null;
    }

    public String setValue(BigDecimal value, String currencyName, String centsName) throws Exception{
        int indexOfDecimalPoint = (value.toString()).indexOf(".");

        // Split and pass interger value of given decimal value to constructor
        String tempIntValue = (value.toString()).substring(0, indexOfDecimalPoint);
        BigInteger intValue = new BigInteger(tempIntValue);

        // Split and pass decimal value of given decimal value to constructor
        String tempDeciValue = (value.toString()).substring(indexOfDecimalPoint+1, value.toString().length());
        @SuppressWarnings("UnusedAssignment")
        BigInteger deciValue = null;

        // Concatenate "0" if decimal value has only single digit
        if(tempDeciValue.length() == 1){
            deciValue = new BigInteger(tempDeciValue.concat("0"));
        }else{
            deciValue = new BigInteger(tempDeciValue);
        }

        this.output = currencyName+" ";
        this.bigValueInWords(intValue);
        this.centsValueInWords(deciValue, centsName);

        return null;
    }

    private String bigValueInWords(BigInteger value) throws Exception{
        // Build scale array
        int exponent = 99;
        for (int i = 0; i < scale.length; i++) {
            scale[i] = new BigInteger("10").pow(exponent);
            exponent = exponent - 3;
        }

        /* Idntify whether given value is a minus value or not
            if == yes then pass value without minus sign
            and pass Minus word to output
        */
        if(value.compareTo(zero) == -1){
            value = new BigInteger(value.toString().substring(1,value.toString().length()));
            output += "Minus ";
        }

        // Get value in words of big numbers (duotrigintillions to thousands)
        for (int i=0; i < scale.length; i++) {
            if((value.divide(scale[i])).compareTo(zero)==1){
            this.index = (int)(value.divide(scale[i])).intValue();
            output += shortValueInWords(this.index) + scaleName[i];
            value = value.mod(scale[i]);
            }
        }

        // Get value in words of short numbers (hundreds, tens and ones)
        output += shortValueInWords((int)(value.intValue()));

        // Get rid of any space at the beginning of output and return value in words
        return this.valueInWords = output.replaceFirst("\\s", "");
    }

    private String shortValueInWords(int shortValue) throws Exception{
        // Get hundreds
        if(String.valueOf(shortValue).length()==3){
            shortValueInWords = ones[shortValue / 100]+" Hundred"+shortValueInWords(shortValue % 100);
        }

        // Get tens
        if(String.valueOf(shortValue).length()== 2 && shortValue >= 20){
            if((shortValue / 10)>=2 && (shortValue % 10)>=0){
                shortValueInWords = tens[shortValue / 10] + ones[shortValue % 10];
            }
        }

        // Get tens between 10 and 20
        if(String.valueOf(shortValue).length()== 2 && shortValue >= 10 && shortValue < 20){
            shortValueInWords = ones[shortValue];
        }

        // Get ones
        if(String.valueOf(shortValue).length()==1){
            shortValueInWords = ones[shortValue];
        }

        return this.shortValueInWords;
    }

    private String decimalValueInWords(BigInteger decimalValue) throws Exception{
        decimalInWords = " Point";
        // Get decimals in point form (0.563 = zero point five six three)
        for(int i=0; i < (decimalValue.toString().length()); i++){
            decimalInWords += ones[Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(decimalValue.toString().charAt(i)))];
        }

        return this.decimalInWords;
    }

    private String centsValueInWords(BigInteger decimalValue, String centsName) throws Exception{
        decimalInWords = " and"+" "+centsName;

        // Get cents in words (5.52 = five and cents fifty two)
        if(decimalValue.intValue() == 0){
            decimalInWords += shortValueInWords(decimalValue.intValue())+" Zero only";
        }else{
            decimalInWords += shortValueInWords(decimalValue.intValue())+" only";
        }


        return this.decimalInWords;
    }

    public String getValueInWords(){
        return this.valueInWords + decimalInWords;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Converter c1 = new Converter();
        Converter c2 = new Converter();
        Converter c3 = new Converter();
        Converter c4 = new Converter();

        try{
            // Get integer value in words
            c1.setValue(new BigInteger("15634886"));
            System.out.println(c1.getValueInWords());

            // Get minus integer value in words
            c2.setValue(new BigInteger("-15634886"));
            System.out.println(c2.getValueInWords());

            // Get decimal value in words
            c3.setValue(new BigDecimal("358621.56895"));
            System.out.println(c3.getValueInWords());

            // Get currency value in words
            c4.setValue(new BigDecimal("358621.56"),"Dollar","Cents");
            System.out.println(c4.getValueInWords());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make the code more readable. This works for numbers within integer range

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution2 {

    static Map<Integer, String> numberMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    static Map<Integer, String> tensMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    static Map<Integer, String> exponentsMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList<String> wordList = new LinkedList<String>();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = scan.nextInt();
        scan.close();

        exponentsMap.put(3, "thousand");
        exponentsMap.put(6, "million");
        exponentsMap.put(9, "billion");

        tensMap.put(2, "twenty");
        tensMap.put(3, "thirty");
        tensMap.put(4, "forty");
        tensMap.put(5, "fifty");
        tensMap.put(6, "sixty");
        tensMap.put(7, "seventy");
        tensMap.put(8, "eighty");
        tensMap.put(9, "ninety");

        numberMap.put(1, "one");
        numberMap.put(2, "two");
        numberMap.put(3, "three");
        numberMap.put(4, "four");
        numberMap.put(5, "five");
        numberMap.put(6, "six");
        numberMap.put(7, "seven");
        numberMap.put(8, "eight");
        numberMap.put(9, "nine");
        numberMap.put(10, "ten");
        numberMap.put(11, "eleven");
        numberMap.put(12, "twelve");
        numberMap.put(13, "thirteen");
        numberMap.put(14, "fourteen");
        numberMap.put(15, "fifteen");
        numberMap.put(16, "sixteen");
        numberMap.put(17, "seventeen");
        numberMap.put(18, "eighteen");
        numberMap.put(19, "nineteen");

        int temp = input;
        
        int exponentCounter =0;
        while(temp>0) {
            // words from 1 to 99
            addLastTwo(temp%100,wordList);
            temp=temp/100;
            
            // add hundreds before exponents
            if(temp!=0) {
                wordList.addFirst("hundred");
                wordList.addFirst(numberMap.getOrDefault(temp%10,""));
                temp = temp/10;
            }
            
            // words for exponents
            if(temp!=0) {
                exponentCounter+=3;
                wordList.addFirst(exponentsMap.getOrDefault(exponentCounter,""));
            }
        }
        wordList.stream().filter(word -> !word.contentEquals("")).forEach(word -> System.out.print(word + " "));
    }

    private static void addLastTwo(int num, LinkedList<String> wordList) {
        if (num > 19) {
            wordList.addFirst(numberMap.getOrDefault(num % 10,""));
            wordList.addFirst(tensMap.getOrDefault(num / 10,""));
            
        } else {
            wordList.addFirst(numberMap.getOrDefault(num,""));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great Work bro!!. but there is one bug in your code. if you type 10014 then it will print ten thousand hundred fourteen.. you just need to check 
if(temp%10 == 0) {
              wordList.addFirst(numberMap.getOrDefault(temp%10,""));
             } else {
              wordList.addFirst("hundred");
                    wordList.addFirst(numberMap.getOrDefault(temp%10,""));
             }
It will fix this bug..

Answer (score 0):

Find this code for Indian rupees and in lakhs & crores than Million and Billion. You can pass String or Bigdecimal to the method. This will give the correct output for paisa as well.

```
package yourpackage;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Currency {
    
    public static String convertToWords(BigDecimal num) {
        return convertToWords(num.toString());
    }

    public static String convertToWords(String num) {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(num);
        long number = bd.longValue();
        long no = bd.longValue();
        int decimal = (int) (bd.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE).doubleValue() * 100);
        int digits_length = String.valueOf(no).length();
        int i = 0;
        ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<Integer, String> words = new HashMap<>();
        words.put(0, "");
        words.put(1, "One");
        words.put(2, "Two");
        words.put(3, "Three");
        words.put(4, "Four");
        words.put(5, "Five");
        words.put(6, "Six");
        words.put(7, "Seven");
        words.put(8, "Eight");
        words.put(9, "Nine");
        words.put(10, "Ten");
        words.put(11, "Eleven");
        words.put(12, "Twelve");
        words.put(13, "Thirteen");
        words.put(14, "Fourteen");
        words.put(15, "Fifteen");
        words.put(16, "Sixteen");
        words.put(17, "Seventeen");
        words.put(18, "Eighteen");
        words.put(19, "Nineteen");
        words.put(20, "Twenty");
        words.put(30, "Thirty");
        words.put(40, "Forty");
        words.put(50, "Fifty");
        words.put(60, "Sixty");
        words.put(70, "Seventy");
        words.put(80, "Eighty");
        words.put(90, "Ninety");
        String digits[] = { "", "Hundred", "Thousand", "Lakh", "Crore" };
        while (i < digits_length) {
            int divider = (i == 2) ? 10 : 100;
            number = no % divider;
            no = no / divider;
            i += divider == 10 ? 1 : 2;
            if (number > 0) {
                int counter = str.size();
                String plural = (counter > 0 && number > 9) ? "s" : "";
                String tmp = (number < 21) ? words.get(Integer.valueOf((int) number)) + " " + digits[counter] + plural
                        : words.get(Integer.valueOf((int) Math.floor(number / 10) * 10)) + " "
                                + words.get(Integer.valueOf((int) (number % 10))) + " " + digits[counter] + plural;
                str.add(tmp);
            } else {
                str.add("");
            }
        }

        Collections.reverse(str);
        String Rupees = String.join(" ", str).trim();

        String paise = (decimal) > 0
                ? " And " + words.get(Integer.valueOf((int) (decimal - decimal % 10))) + " "
                        + words.get(Integer.valueOf((int) (decimal % 10))) + " Paise "
                : "";
        return "Rupees " + Rupees + paise + " Only";
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("56721351 = " + Currency.convertToWords(new BigDecimal(56721351)));
        System.out.println("76521351.61 = " + Currency.convertToWords("76521351.61"));
    }

}
```

When you run this program for 56721351(as Bigdecimal) and 76521351.61(as String) the output is

```
56721351 = Rupees Five Crore Sixty Seven Lakhs Twenty One Thousands Three Hundred Fifty One Only
76521351.61 = Rupees Seven Crore Sixty Five Lakhs Twenty One Thousands Three Hundred Fifty One And Sixty One Paise  Only
```

Answer (score 0):

Below java program demonstrate how to convert a number from zero to one million.

NumberToStringLiteral class :

```
public class NumberToStringLiteral
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        NumberToStringLiteral numberToStringLiteral = new NumberToStringLiteral();
        int number = 123456;
        String stringLiteral = numberToStringLiteral.convertIntegerToStringLiteral(number);
        System.out.println(stringLiteral);
    }
    
    private String convertIntegerToStringLiteral(int number)
    {
        if (number < 100)
            return from_0_To_100(number);
        
        if ( number >= 100 && number < 1000 )
            return from_101_To_999(number);
        
        if ( number >= 1000 && number <= 99999)
            return from_1000_To_99999(number);
        
        if (number <= 1000000)
            return from_100000_and_above(number);
        
        return Digits.OVER_ONE_MILLION.getStringLiteral();
    }
    
    private String from_0_To_100(int number)
    {
        if (number <= 19 )
            return ZeroToNineteen.getStringLiteral(number);
        
        String LastDigit = ( ZeroToNineteen.getStringLiteral(number % 10) != ZeroToNineteen.ZERO.getStringLiteral() ) ? 
                            ZeroToNineteen.getStringLiteral(number % 10) : "";
        return Tens.getStringLiteralFromNumber( (number - (number % 10 )) ) + " " + LastDigit;
    }
    
    private String from_101_To_999(int number)
    {
        String LastDigit = ( ZeroToNineteen.getStringLiteral(number % 100) != ZeroToNineteen.ZERO.getStringLiteral() ) ?
                            ZeroToNineteen.getStringLiteral(number % 100)  : "";
        
        if ( (number % 100) > 19)
            LastDigit = from_0_To_100(number % 100);
            
        if (LastDigit.isBlank())
            return ZeroToNineteen.getStringLiteral(number / 100 ) + Digits.getStringLiteral(getNumberOfDigit(0));
            
        return ZeroToNineteen.getStringLiteral(number / 100 ) + Digits.getStringLiteral(getNumberOfDigit(number)) + LastDigit;
    }
        
    private String from_1000_To_99999(int number)
    {
        String LastDigit = (number % 1000 < 20 ) ? from_0_To_100(number % 1000) : from_101_To_999(number % 1000);
        
        if (LastDigit.equalsIgnoreCase(ZeroToNineteen.ZERO.getStringLiteral()))
            LastDigit = "";
        
        return from_0_To_100(number / 1000 ) + Digits.getStringLiteral(getNumberOfDigit(number)) + LastDigit;
    }
    
    private String from_100000_and_above(int number)
    {
        if (number == 1000000)
            return Digits.ONE_MILLION.getStringLiteral();
        
        String lastThreeDigit = (number % 1000 <= 100)  ? from_0_To_100(number % 1000) : from_101_To_999(number % 1000);
        
        if (lastThreeDigit.equalsIgnoreCase(ZeroToNineteen.ZERO.toString()))
            lastThreeDigit = "";
        
        String number1 = from_101_To_999(number / 1000) + Digits.THOUSAND.getStringLiteral() +  lastThreeDigit;
        return String.valueOf(number1);
    }
    
    private int getNumberOfDigit(int number)
    {
        int count = 0;
        while ( number != 0 )
        {
            number /=  10;
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

ZeroToNineteen enum :

```
public enum ZeroToNineteen
{
    ZERO(0, "zero"), 
    ONE(1, "one"),
    TWO(2, "two"),
    THREE(3, "three"),
    FOUR(4, "four"),
    FIVE(5, "five"),
    SIX(6, "six"),
    SEVEN(7, "seven"),
    EIGHT(8, "eight"),
    NINE(9, "nine"),
    TEN(10, "ten"),
    ELEVEN(11, "eleven"),
    TWELVE(12, "twelve"),
    THIRTEEN(13, "thirteen"),
    FOURTEEN(14, "fourteen"),
    FIFTEEN(15, "fifteen"),
    SIXTEEN(16, "sixteen"),
    SEVENTEEN(17, "seventeen"),
    EIGHTEEN(18, "eighteen"),
    NINETEEN(19, "nineteen");
    
    
    private int number;
    private String stringLiteral;
    public static Map<Integer, String> stringLiteralMap;
    
    ZeroToNineteen(int number, String stringLiteral)
    {
        this.number = number;
        this.stringLiteral = stringLiteral;
    }
    
    public int getNumber()
    {
        return this.number;
    }
    
    public String getStringLiteral()
    {
        return this.stringLiteral;
    }
    
    public static String getStringLiteral(int number)
    {
        if (stringLiteralMap == null)
            addData();
        
        return stringLiteralMap.get(number);
    }
    
    private static void addData()
    {
        stringLiteralMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (ZeroToNineteen zeroToNineteen : ZeroToNineteen.values())
        {
            stringLiteralMap.put(zeroToNineteen.getNumber(), zeroToNineteen.getStringLiteral());
        }
    }
}
```

Tens enum :

```
public enum Tens
{
    TEN(10, "ten"),
    TWENTY(20, "twenty"),
    THIRTY(30, "thirty"),
    FORTY(40, "forty"),
    FIFTY(50, "fifty"),
    SIXTY(60, "sixty"),
    SEVENTY(70, "seventy"),
    EIGHTY(80, "eighty"),
    NINETY(90, "ninety"),
    HUNDRED(100, "one hundred");
    
    
    private int number;
    private String stringLiteral;
    private static Map<Integer, String> stringLiteralMap;
    
    Tens(int number, String stringLiteral)
    {
        this.number = number;
        this.stringLiteral = stringLiteral;
    }
    
    public int getNumber()
    {
        return this.number;
    }
    
    public String getStringLiteral()
    {
        return this.stringLiteral;
    }
    
    public static String getStringLiteralFromNumber(int number)
    {
        if (stringLiteralMap == null)
            addDataToStringLiteralMap();
        
        return stringLiteralMap.get(number);
    }
    
    private static void addDataToStringLiteralMap()
    {
        stringLiteralMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        for (Tens tens : Tens.values())
            stringLiteralMap.put(tens.getNumber(), tens.getStringLiteral());
    }
}
```

Digits enum :

```
public enum Digits
{
    HUNDRED(3, " hundred and "),
    THOUSAND(4, " thousand "),
    TEN_THOUSAND(5," thousand "),
    ONLY_HUNDRED(0, " hundred" ),
    ONE_MILLION(1000000, "one million"),
    OVER_ONE_MILLION(1000001, "over one million");
    
    private int digit;
    private String stringLiteral;
    private static Map<Integer, String> stringLiteralMap;
    
    private Digits(int digit, String stringLiteral)
    {
        this.digit = digit;
        this.stringLiteral = stringLiteral;
    }
    
    public int getDigit()
    {
        return this.digit;
    }
    
    public String getStringLiteral()
    {
        return this.stringLiteral;
    }
    
    public static String getStringLiteral(int number)
    {
        if ( stringLiteralMap == null )
            addStringLiteralMap();
        
        return stringLiteralMap.get(number);
    }
    
    private static void addStringLiteralMap()
    {
        stringLiteralMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        for ( Digits digits : Digits.values() )
            stringLiteralMap.put(digits.getDigit(), digits.getStringLiteral());
    }
}
```

Output :

```
one hundred and twenty three thousand four hundred and fifty six
```

Note: I have used all three enum for constant variables, you can also use array.

Hope this will help you, Let me know if you have any doubt in comment section.

Answer (score 0):

```
//international number system
static String point = "point";
static String h = "hundred";
static String th = "thousand";
static String m = "million";
static String b = "billion";

static String 
            _0 = "",
            _1 = "one",
            _2 = "two",
            _3 = "three",
            _4 = "four",""
            _5 = "five",
            _6 = "six",
            _7 = "seven",
            _8 = "eight",
            _9 = "nine";
static String 
            _00 = "",
            _10 = "ten",
            _20 = "twenty",
            _30 = "thirty",
            _40 = "forty",
            _50 = "fifty",
            _60 = "sixty",
            _70 = "seventy",
            _80 = "eighty",
            _90 = "ninety";
static String  
            _11 = "eleven",
            _12 = "twelve",
            _13 = "thirteen",
            _14 = "forteen",
            _15 = "fifteen",
            _16 = "sixteen",
            _17 = "seventeen",
            _18 = "eighteen",
            _19 = "nineteen";
static String 
            _000 = "",
            _100 = _1 + " " + h,
            _200 = _2 + " " + h,
            _300 = _3 + " " + h,
            _400 = _4 + " " + h,
            _500 = _5 + " " + h,
            _600 = _6 + " " + h,
            _700 = _7 + " " + h,
            _800 = _8 + " " + h,
            _900 = _9 + " " + h;   

static String[][][] numberNames = new String[][][]{
        {
            {_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9},
            {_00, _10, _20, _30, _40, _50, _60, _70, _80, _90},
            {_000, _100, _200, _300, _400, _500, _600, _700, _800, _900}
        },
        {
            {_0, _1+" "+th, _2+" "+th, _3+" "+th, _4+" "+th, _5+" "+th,
            _6+" "+th, _7+" "+th, _8+" "+th, _9+" "+th},
            {_00, _10, _20, _30, _40, _50, _60, _70, _80, _90},
            {_000, _100, _200, _300, _400, _500, _600, _700, _800, _900}
        },
        {
            {_0, _1+" "+m, _2+" "+m, _3+" "+m, _4+" "+m, _5+" "+m,
            _6+" "+m, _7+" "+m, _8+" "+m, _9+" "+m},
            {_00, _10, _20, _30, _40, _50, _60, _70, _80, _90},
            {_000, _100, _200, _300, _400, _500, _600, _700, _800, _900}
        },
        {
            {_0, _1+" "+b, _2+" "+b, _3+" "+b, _4+" "+b, _5+" "+b,
            _6+" "+b, _7+" "+b, _8+" "+b, _9+" "+b},
            {_00, _10, _20, _30, _40, _50, _60, _70, _80, _90},
            {_000, _100, _200, _300, _400, _500, _600, _700, _800, _900}
        }
};

//indian number system
static String l = "lakh";
static String c = "crore";
static String a = "arab";

static String[][][] indianNumberNames = new String[][][]{
    {
        {_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9},
        {_00, _10, _20, _30, _40, _50, _60, _70, _80, _90},
        {_000, _100, _200, _300, _400, _500, _600, _700, _800, _900}
    },
    {
        {_0, _1+" "+th, _2+" "+th, _3+" "+th, _4+" "+th, _5+" "+th,
        _6+" "+th, _7+" "+th, _8+" "+th, _9+" "+th},
        {_00, _10, _20, _30, _40, _50, _60, _70, _80, _90}
    },
    {
        {_0, _1+" "+l, _2+" "+l, _3+" "+l, _4+" "+l, _5+" "+l,
        _6+" "+l, _7+" "+l, _8+" "+l, _9+" "+l},
        {_00, _10, _20, _30, _40, _50, _60, _70, _80, _90}
    },
    {
        {_0, _1+" "+c, _2+" "+c, _3+" "+c, _4+" "+c, _5+" "+c,
        _6+" "+c, _7+" "+c, _8+" "+c, _9+" "+c},
        {_00, _10, _20, _30, _40, _50, _60, _70, _80, _90}
    },
    {
        {_0, _1+" "+a, _2+" "+a, _3+" "+a, _4+" "+a, _5+" "+a,
        _6+" "+a, _7+" "+a, _8+" "+a, _9+" "+a},
        {_00, _10, _20, _30, _40, _50, _60, _70, _80, _90}
    }
};

//the grouping of numbers,
//such as 1 000 000 000 where each group contains 3 digits,
//or 1 00 00 00 000 for indian number system,
//where each group contains 2 digits except the first group which has 3.
//may differ from one number system to another.
static int place_difference = 3;

//current number system
static int curNumSys = INTERNATIONAL_NUMBER_SYSTEM;

public static String convertToNumberName(String number){
    String[] split = number.split("\\.");
    String num1, num2;
    num1 = split[0];
    num2 = split.length > 1 ? split[1] : "";

    int place_counter = 0;
    int step = 0;
    Stack<String> numberNameBuilder = new Stack<>();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append(num1);
    num1 = (builder.reverse()).toString();
    builder.setLength(0);

    int counter = -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < num1.length(); i++){
        int c = Integer.parseInt(num1.charAt(i) + "");
        counter++;
        place_counter = counter % place_difference;
        if (place_counter == 0){
            step++;
            //specific number system component, this is for indian number system
            //find a generic approach at a later time
            // if (step == 2){
            //     counter = 0;
            //     place_difference = 2;
            // }
        }
        String name = getDataSet()[step - 1][place_counter][c];
        numberNameBuilder.push(name);
    }

    while(numberNameBuilder.hasNext()){
        builder.append(numberNameBuilder.pop() + " ");
    }
    
    String str = builder.toString();
    str = refine(str);

    builder.setLength(0);
    builder.append(num2);
    num2 = builder.reverse().toString();
    builder.setLength(0);

    //decimal conversion here
    for(int i = 0; i < num2.length(); i++){
        int c = Integer.parseInt(num2.charAt(i) + "");
        numberNameBuilder.push(getDataSet()[0][0][c]);
    }

    while(numberNameBuilder.hasNext()){
        builder.append(numberNameBuilder.pop() + " ");
    }

    str += point + " ";
    str += builder.toString();
    
    return str;
}

private static String refine(String str){
    str = str.replace(_10 + " " + _1, _11);
    str = str.replace(_10 + " " + _2, _12);
    str = str.replace(_10 + " " + _3, _13);
    str = str.replace(_10 + " " + _4, _14);
    str = str.replace(_10 + " " + _5, _15);
    str = str.replace(_10 + " " + _6, _16);
    str = str.replace(_10 + " " + _7, _17);
    str = str.replace(_10 + " " + _8, _18);
    str = str.replace(_10 + " " + _9, _19);
    return str;
}

private static String[][][] getDataSet(){
    switch(curNumSys){
        case INDIAN_NUMBER_SYSTEM :
            return indianNumberNames;
        case INTERNATIONAL_NUMBER_SYSTEM :
            return numberNames;
    }
    return numberNames;
}
```

Just simply call the convertToNumberName() function and give the numbers as string,to change from international to Indian, simply uncomment the commented lines in the function mentioned above, to add more number systems, more data sets and minor tweaking in the function will be required.

The stack mentioned here is just a simple LIFO structure and with ordinary stack functions, one could use their own custom implementation of the stack here or just import from Java.

The limit can be expanded further, for example, international number system only has capacity to convert up-to 999 billions, however, the data set can be expanded further to add trillions and quadrillions and more, it can go as far as the dataset that is the 3d array in code above allows it to.

Answer (score 0):

Simple java Programe

```
class SimpleJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          int n = 123456789;
           System.out.println(n+" To "+convertNumberToWord(n));
            n = 12345678;
           System.out.println(n+" To "+convertNumberToWord(n));
            n = 1234567;
           System.out.println(n+" To "+convertNumberToWord(n));
            n = 123456;
           System.out.println(n+" To "+convertNumberToWord(n));
            n = 12345;
           System.out.println(n+" To "+convertNumberToWord(n));
            n = 1234;
           System.out.println(n+" To "+convertNumberToWord(n));
            n = 123;
           System.out.println(n+" To "+convertNumberToWord(n));
            n = 12;
           System.out.println(n+" To "+convertNumberToWord(n));
            n = 1;
           System.out.println(n+" To "+convertNumberToWord(n));
            n = 0;
           System.out.println(n+" To "+convertNumberToWord(n));
    }
    
    private static final String[] units = {
        "", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen"
    };
    private static final String[] tens = {
        "", "", "Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety"
    };
    
     public static String convertNumberToWord(int number) {
        if (number == 0) {
            return "Zero";
        }
        if (number < 0) {
            return "Minus " + convertNumberToWord(Math.abs(number));
        }
        if (number < 20) {
            return units[number];
        }
        if (number < 100) {
            return tens[number / 10] + ((number % 10 != 0) ? " " : "") + units[number % 10];
        }
        if (number < 1000) {
            return units[number / 100] + " Hundred" + ((number % 100 != 0) ? " " : "") + convertNumberToWord(number % 100);
        }
        if (number < 100000) {
            return convertNumberToWord(number / 1000) + " Thousand" + ((number % 1000 != 0) ? " " : "") + convertNumberToWord(number % 1000);
        }
        if (number < 10000000) {
            return convertNumberToWord(number / 100000) + " Lakh" + ((number % 100000 != 0) ? " " : "") + convertNumberToWord(number % 100000);
        }
        if (number < 1000000000) {
            return convertNumberToWord(number / 10000000) + " Crore" + ((number % 10000000 != 0) ? " " : "") + convertNumberToWord(number % 10000000);
        }
        return "Number out of range";
    }
  
}
```

Output

```
123456789 To Twelve Crore Thirty Four Lakh Fifty Six Thousand Seven Hundred Eighty Nine
12345678 To One Crore Twenty Three Lakh Forty Five Thousand Six Hundred Seventy Eight
1234567 To Twelve Lakh Thirty Four Thousand Five Hundred Sixty Seven
123456 To One Lakh Twenty Three Thousand Four Hundred Fifty Six
12345 To Twelve Thousand Three Hundred Forty Five
1234 To One Thousand Two Hundred Thirty Four
123 To One Hundred Twenty Three
12 To Twelve
1 To One
0 To Zero
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need number to word conversion in Lithuanian, Latvian, Estonian, English or Russian languages, you can find implementation here [num2word](https://github.com/labai/la-utils/tree/main/num2word)

Answer (score -1):

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringToNum {
public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the no: ");
    int  no=sc.nextInt();
    int arrNum[]=new int[10];
    int i=0;
    while(no!=0)
    {
      arrNum[i]=no%10;
      no=no/10;
      i++;
    }
    int len=i;
    int arrNum1[]=new int[len];
    int j=0;
    for(int k=len-1;k>=0;k--)
    {
        arrNum1[j]=arrNum[k];
        j++;
    }
    StringToNum stn=new StringToNum();
    String output="";
    switch(len)
    {
      case 1:
      {
         output+=stn.strNum1(arrNum1[len-1]);
         System.out.println("output="+output);
         break;
      }
      case 2:
      {
        int no1=arrNum1[len-2]*10+arrNum1[len-1];
        if(no1>=11 & no1<=19)
        {
         output=stn.strNum2(no1);
        // output=output+" "+stn.strNum1(arrNum1[len-1]);
         System.out.println("output="+output);
        }
        else
        {
         arrNum1[len-2]=arrNum1[len-2]*10;
         output+=stn.strNum2(arrNum1[len-2]);
         output=output+" "+stn.strNum1(arrNum1[len-1]);
         System.out.println("output="+output);
        }
         break;
      }
      case 3:
      {
        output=stn.strNum1(arrNum1[len-3])+" hundred ";
        int no1=arrNum1[len-2]*10+arrNum1[len-1];
        if(no1>=11 & no1<=19)
        {
         output=stn.strNum2(no1);
        }
        else
        {
         arrNum1[len-2]=arrNum1[len-2]*10;
         output+=stn.strNum2(arrNum1[len-2]);
         output=output+" "+stn.strNum1(arrNum1[len-1]);
        }
        System.out.println("output="+output);  
        break;
      }
      case 4:
      {
        output=stn.strNum1(arrNum1[len-4])+" thousand ";
        if(!stn.strNum1(arrNum1[len - 3]).equals(""))
        {
        output+=stn.strNum1(arrNum1[len-3])+" hundred ";
        }
        int no1=arrNum1[len-2]*10+arrNum1[len-1];
        if(no1>=11 & no1<=19)
        {
         output=stn.strNum2(no1);
        }
        else
        {
         arrNum1[len-2]=arrNum1[len-2]*10;
         output+=stn.strNum2(arrNum1[len-2]);
         output=output+" "+stn.strNum1(arrNum1[len-1]);
        }
        System.out.println("output="+output);
        break;
      }

      case 5:
      {
        int no1=arrNum1[len-5]*10+arrNum1[len-4];
        if(no1>=11 & no1<=19)
        {
         output=stn.strNum2(no1)+" thousand ";
        }
        else
        {
         arrNum1[len-5]=arrNum1[len-5]*10;
         output+=stn.strNum2(arrNum1[len-5]);
         output=output+" "+stn.strNum1(arrNum1[len-4])+" thousand ";
        }
        if( !stn.strNum1(arrNum1[len - 3]).equals(""))
        {
        output+=stn.strNum1(arrNum1[len-3])+" hundred ";
        }
        no1 = arrNum1[len - 2] * 10 + arrNum1[len - 1];
        if(no1>=11 & no1<=19)
        {
         output=stn.strNum2(no1);
        }
        else
        {
         arrNum1[len-2]=arrNum1[len-2]*10;
         output+=stn.strNum2(arrNum1[len-2]);
         output=output+" "+stn.strNum1(arrNum1[len-1]);
        }
        System.out.println("output="+output);
        break;
      }
      case 6:
      {
        output+=stn.strNum1(arrNum1[len-6])+" million ";
        int no1=arrNum1[len-5]*10+arrNum1[len-4];
        if(no1>=11 & no1<=19)
        {
         output+=stn.strNum2(no1)+" thousand ";
        }
        else
        {
         arrNum1[len-5]=arrNum1[len-5]*10;
         output+=stn.strNum2(arrNum1[len-5]);
         output=output+" "+stn.strNum1(arrNum1[len-4])+" thousand ";
        }
        if( !stn.strNum1(arrNum1[len - 3]).equals(""))
        {
        output+=stn.strNum1(arrNum1[len-3])+" hundred ";
        }
        no1 = arrNum1[len - 2] * 10 + arrNum1[len - 1];
        if(no1>=11 & no1<=19)
        {
         output=stn.strNum2(no1);
        }
        else
        {
         arrNum1[len-2]=arrNum1[len-2]*10;
         output+=stn.strNum2(arrNum1[len-2]);
         output=output+" "+stn.strNum1(arrNum1[len-1]);
        }
        System.out.println("output="+output);
        break;
      }
      case 7:
      {
        int no1=arrNum1[len-7]*10+arrNum1[len-6];
        if(no1>=11 & no1<=19)
        {
         output=stn.strNum2(no1)+" Milloin ";
        }
        else
        {
         arrNum1[len-7]=arrNum1[len-7]*10;
         output+=stn.strNum2(arrNum1[len-7]);
         output=output+" "+stn.strNum1(arrNum1[len-6])+" Million ";
        }
        no1=arrNum1[len-5]*10+arrNum1[len-4];
        if(no1>=11 & no1<=19)
        {
         output=stn.strNum2(no1)+" Thousand ";
        }
        else
        {
         arrNum1[len-5]=arrNum1[len-5]*10;
         output+=stn.strNum2(arrNum1[len-5]);
         output=output+" "+stn.strNum1(arrNum1[len-4])+" Thousand ";
        }
        if( !stn.strNum1(arrNum1[len - 3]).equals(""))
        {
        output+=stn.strNum1(arrNum1[len-3])+" Hundred ";
        }
        no1 = arrNum1[len - 2] * 10 + arrNum1[len - 1];
        if(no1>=11 & no1<=19)
        {
         output=stn.strNum2(no1);
        }
        else
        {
         arrNum1[len-2]=arrNum1[len-2]*10;
         output+=stn.strNum2(arrNum1[len-2]);
         output=output+" "+stn.strNum1(arrNum1[len-1]);
        }
        System.out.println("output="+output);
        break;
      }
    }

  }
  String strNum1(int a)
  {
    String op="";
    switch(a)
    {
     case 1:
     {
     op="one";
     break;
     }
     case 2:
     {
     op="two";
     break;
     }
     case 3:
     {
     op="three";
     break;
     }
     case 4:
     {
     op="four";
     break;
     }
     case 5:
     {
     op="five";
     break;
     }
     case 6:
     {
     op="six";
     break;
     }
     case 7:
     {
     op="seven";
     break;
     }
     case 8:
     {
     op="eight";
     break;
     }
     case 9:
     {
     op="nine";
     break;
     }
    }
    return op;
  }
  String strNum2(int a)
  {
    String op="";
    switch(a)
    {
     case 10:
     {
     op="ten";
     break;
     }
     case 20:
     {
     op="twenty";
     break;
     }
     case 30:
     {
     op="thirty";
     break;
     }
     case 40:
     {
     op="fourty";
     break;
     }
     case 50:
     {
     op="fifty";
     break;
     }
     case 60:
     {
     op="sixty";
     break;
     }
     case 70:
     {
     op="seventy";
     break;
     }
     case 80:
     {
     op="eighty";
     break;
     }
     case 90:
     {
     op="ninty";
     break;
     }
     case 11:
     {
     op="eleven";
     break;
     }
     case 12:
     {
     op="twelve";
     break;
     }
     case 13:
     {
     op="thirteen";
     break;
     }
     case 14:
     {
     op="fourteen";
     break;
     }
     case 15:
     {
     op="fifteen";
     break;
     }
     case 16:
     {
     op="sixteen";
     break;
     }
     case 17:
     {
     op="seventeen";
     break;
     }
     case 18:
     {
     op="eighteen";
     break;
     }
     case 19:
     {
     op="nineteen";
     break;
     }
    }
    return op;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/* This program will print words for a number between 0 to 99999*/

    public class NumberInWords5Digits {

        static int testcase1 = 93284;

        public static void main(String args[]){
            NumberInWords5Digits testInstance = new NumberInWords5Digits();
            String result = testInstance.inWords(testcase1);
            System.out.println("Result : "+result);
        }

        //write your code here
        public String inWords(int num){
            int digit = 0;
            String word = "";
            int temp = num;
            while(temp>0)
            {
                if(temp%10 >= 0)
                    digit++;
                temp = temp/10;
            }

            if(num == 0)
                return "zero";

            System.out.println(num);
            if(digit == 1)
                word = inTens(num, digit);
            else if(digit == 2)
                word = inTens(num, digit);
            else if(digit == 3)
                word = inHundreds(num, digit);
            else if(digit == 4)
                word = inThousands(num, digit);
            else if(digit == 5)
                word = inThousands(num, digit);
            return word;
        }

        public String inTens(int num, int digit){
            int tens = 0;
            int units = 0;
            if(digit == 2)      
            {
                tens = num/10;
                units = num%10;
            }
            String unit = "";
            String ten = "";
            String word = "";

            if(num == 10)
            {word = "ten"; return word;}

            if(num == 11)
            {word = "eleven"; return word;}
            if(num == 12)
            {word = "twelve"; return word;}
            if(num == 13)
            {word = "thirteen"; return word;}
            if(num == 14)
            {word = "fourteen"; return word;}
            if(num == 15)
            {word = "fifteen"; return word;}
            if(num == 16)
            {word = "sixteen"; return word;}
            if(num == 17)
            {word = "seventeen"; return word;}
            if(num == 18)
            {word = "eighteen"; return word;}
            if(num == 19)
            {word = "nineteen"; return word;}

            if(units == 1 || num == 1)
                unit = "one";
            else if(units == 2 || num == 2)
                unit = "two";
            else if(units == 3 || num == 3)
                unit = "three";
            else if(units == 4 || num == 4)
                unit = "four";
            else if(units == 5 || num == 5)
                unit = "five";
            else if(units == 6 || num == 6)
                unit = "six";
            else if(units == 7 || num == 7)
                unit = "seven";
            else if(units == 8 || num == 8)
                unit = "eight";
            else if(units == 9 || num == 9)
                unit = "nine";

            if(tens == 2)
                ten = "twenty";
            else if(tens == 3)
                ten = "thirty";
            else if(tens == 4)
                ten = "forty";
            else if(tens == 5)
                ten = "fifty";
            else if(tens == 6)
                ten = "sixty";
            else if(tens == 7)
                ten = "seventy";
            else if(tens == 8)
                ten = "eighty";
            else if(tens == 9)
                ten = "ninety";

            if(digit == 1)
                word = unit;
            else if(digit == 2)
                word = ten + " " + unit;
            return word;
        }

        //inHundreds(525, 3)
        public String inHundreds(int num, int digit){

            int hundreds = num/100; // =5
            int tensAndUnits = num%100; // =25
            String hundred = "";
            String tenAndUnit = "";
            String word = "";

            tenAndUnit = inTens(tensAndUnits, 2);

            if(hundreds == 1)
                hundred = "one hundred";
            else if(hundreds == 2)
                hundred = "two hundred";
            else if(hundreds == 3)
                hundred = "three hundred";
            else if(hundreds == 4)
                hundred = "four hundred";
            else if(hundreds == 5)
                hundred = "five hundred";
            else if(hundreds == 6)
                hundred = "six hundred";
            else if(hundreds == 7)
                hundred = "seven hundred";
            else if(hundreds == 8)
                hundred = "eight hundred";
            else if(hundreds == 9)
                hundred = "nine hundred";

            word = hundred + " " + tenAndUnit;
            return word;
        }

        public String inThousands(int num, int digit){

            int thousands = 0;      
            int hundredsAndOthers = num%1000;
            String thousand = "";
            String hundredAndOther = "";
            String word = "";
            if(digit == 5)
            {
                thousands = num/1000;
                thousand = inTens(thousands, 2);            
            }
            else if(digit == 4)
            {
                thousands = num/1000;
                thousand = inTens(thousands, 1);
            }

            if(hundredsAndOthers/100 == 0) // in case of "023"
                hundredAndOther = inTens(hundredsAndOthers, 2);
            else
                hundredAndOther = inHundreds(hundredsAndOthers, 3);

            word = thousand + " thousand " + hundredAndOther;

            return word;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
public class rupee
{
public static void main(String[] args)throws  IOException
{

 int len=0,revnum=0,i,dup=0,j=0,k=0;
 int gvalue;
  String[] ones={"one","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Eleven","Twelve","Thirteen","Fourteen","Fifteen","Sixteen","Seventeen","Eighteen","Nineteen",""};
    String[] twos={"Ten","Twenty","Thirty","Fourty","fifty","Sixty","Seventy","eighty","Ninety",""};
System.out.println("\n Enter value");
InputStreamReader b=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(b);
gvalue=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
if(gvalue==10)

System.out.println("Ten");

else if(gvalue==100)

System.out.println("Hundred");

else if(gvalue==1000)
System.out.println("Thousand");

dup=gvalue;
for(i=0;dup>0;i++)
{
revnum=revnum*10+dup%10;
len++;
dup=dup/10;
}
while(j<len)
{
if(gvalue<10)
{
System.out.println(ones[gvalue-1]);
}
else if(gvalue>10&&gvalue<=19)
{
System.out.println(ones[gvalue-2]);
break;
}
else if(gvalue>19&&gvalue<100)
{
k=gvalue/10;
gvalue=gvalue%10;
System.out.println(twos[k-1]);
}
else if(gvalue>100&&gvalue<1000)
{
k=gvalue/100;
gvalue=gvalue%100;
System.out.println(ones[k-1] +"Hundred");
}
else if(gvalue>=1000&&gvalue<9999)
{
k=gvalue/1000;
gvalue=gvalue%1000;
System.out.println(ones[k-1]+"Thousand");
    }
else if(gvalue>=11000&&gvalue<=19000)
{
    k=gvalue/1000;
    gvalue=gvalue%1000;
    System.out.println(twos[k-2]+"Thousand");
}       
else if(gvalue>=12000&&gvalue<100000)
{
k=gvalue/10000;
    gvalue=gvalue%10000;
System.out.println(ones[gvalue-1]);
}
else
{
System.out.println("");
    }
j++;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score -4):

I have used 2 dimensional array...

```
   import java.util.Scanner;


   public class numberEnglish {
   public static void main(String args[])
        {
    String[ ][ ] aryNumbers = new String[9][4];
    aryNumbers[0][0] = "one";
    aryNumbers[0][1] = "ten";
    aryNumbers[0][2] = "one hundred and";
    aryNumbers[0][3] = "one thousand";

    aryNumbers[1][0] = "two";
    aryNumbers[1][1] = "twenty";
    aryNumbers[1][2] = "two hundred and";
    aryNumbers[1][3] = "two thousand";

    aryNumbers[2][0] = "three";
    aryNumbers[2][1] = "thirty";
    aryNumbers[2][2] = "three hundred and";
    aryNumbers[2][3] = "three thousand";

    aryNumbers[3][0] = "four";
    aryNumbers[3][1] = "fourty";
    aryNumbers[3][2] = "four hundred and";
    aryNumbers[3][3] = "four thousand";

    aryNumbers[4][0] = "five";
    aryNumbers[4][1] = "fifty";
    aryNumbers[4][2] = "five hundred and";
    aryNumbers[4][3] = "five thousand";

    aryNumbers[5][0] = "six";
    aryNumbers[5][1] = "sixty";
    aryNumbers[5][2] = "six hundred and";
    aryNumbers[5][3] = "six thousand";

    aryNumbers[6][0] = "seven";
    aryNumbers[6][1] = "seventy";
    aryNumbers[6][2] = "seven hundred and";
    aryNumbers[6][3] = "seven thousand";

    aryNumbers[7][0] = "eight";
    aryNumbers[7][1] = "eighty";
    aryNumbers[7][2] = "eight hundred and";
    aryNumbers[7][3] = "eight thousand";

    aryNumbers[8][0] = "nine";
    aryNumbers[8][1] = "ninty";
    aryNumbers[8][2] = "nine hundred and";
    aryNumbers[8][3] = "nine thousand";


    //System.out.println(aryNumbers[0] + " "+aryNumbers[0] + " ");

    int number=0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(" Enter Number 4 digited number:: ");
    number = sc.nextInt();
    int temp = number;
    int count=1;
    String english="";
    String tenglish = "";
    if(number == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("*********");
        System.out.println("Zero");
        System.out.println("*********");
        sc.close();
        return;
    }
    while(temp !=0)
    {

        int r = temp%10;
        if(r==0)
        {
            tenglish = " zero ";
            count++;
        }
        else
        {

            int t1=r-1;
            int t2 = count-1;
            //System.out.println(t1 +" "+t2);
            count++;
            tenglish = aryNumbers[t1][t2];

            //System.out.println(aryNumbers[t1][t2]);
        }
        english = tenglish +" "+ english;
        temp = temp/10;

    }
    //System.out.println(aryNumbers[0][0]);
    english = english.replace("ten  zero", "ten");
    english = english.replace("twenty  zero", "twenty");
    english = english.replace("thirty  zero", "thirty");
    english = english.replace("fourty  zero", "fourty");
    english = english.replace("fifty  zero", "fifty");
    english = english.replace("sixty  zero", "sixty");
    english = english.replace("seventy  zero", "seventy");
    english = english.replace("eighty  zero", "eighty");
    english = english.replace("ninety  zero", "ninety");

    english = english.replace("ten one", "eleven");
    english = english.replace("ten two", "twelve");
    english = english.replace("ten three", "thirteen");
    english = english.replace("ten four", "fourteen");
    english = english.replace("ten five", "fifteen");
    english = english.replace("ten six", "sixteen");
    english = english.replace("ten seven", "seventeen");
    english = english.replace("ten eight", "eighteen");
    english = english.replace("ten nine", "nineteen");
    english = english.replace(" zero ", "");
    int length = english.length();
    String sub = english.substring(length-6,length-3);
    //System.out.println(length);
    //System.out.println(sub);
    if(sub.equals("and"))
    {
        //System.out.println("hello");
        english=english.substring(0,length-6);
    }
    System.out.println("********************************************");
    System.out.println(english);
    System.out.println("********************************************");
    sc.close();
}
```

}

Comment: This code has a bug. You've spelled 90 as "ninty" in one location and "ninety" in another.