# Convert BigDecimal to String for a check

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Is there a library or a call that will convert a BigDecimal value to a string to print on checks?

Example: 1323.03

One Thousand Three Hundred Twenty-Three Dollars and Three Cents

I have seen some examples that create a recursive function to do this but I was wondering if it was part of any standard library?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert number to words in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911966/how-to-convert-number-to-words-in-java)

Comment: Thanks.  I searched and did not come across the possible duplicate link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this class [EnglishNumberToWords](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0426.html) that is doing what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it does not exist as part of any standard library. It's just too rarely used and there are so many ways of doing it (e.g. your way only work for conversion into English of currency amount, assuming dollars and cents).