# Trying to use Switch statements within a loop in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

I am trying to get practice on loops and switch statements and trying to figure out the following issue.

The output depends on the integer `day` value.
For example if the user enters `8` then it will print the first 8 lines as follows:

```
On the 8th day of holidays, I did Eight jumping jacks,
....
...
On the 3rd day of holidays, I did Three pull downs,
...
..
On the 1st day of holidays, I did One downhill sprint.
```

So to solve this problem, I have used a switch statement in a `for` loop and then wanted to use another switch statement to put the appropriate suffix for the day number. Eg: 1st, 2nd etc

I have done the following but I am stuck badly and would really appreciate if they can help me out.

```
 int day = in.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < day; i++) {
            switch (day) {

                // Also, do I add another switch statement here for suffix?


            }
        }
```

Comment: I am a little confused as I don't see a System.out.println() statement anywhere here. You have, as I see it, 2 things changing ... you have the xth day, which you could create by joining a string to a temporary variable, and you have the word "Eight", "Seven", etc., which you could store and look-up. Why are you using the switch statement & could you do without it (or is it a firm requirement for inclusion)?

Comment: This question has already been answered by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6810409/256196).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the number to a word can be done with a switch statement, in the case where you are having a limited (and small) number. For example, only numbers one to 10.

It would be as follows:

```
String numberWord;

switch (day)
{
case 1:
    suffix = "one";
    break;
case 2:
    suffix = "two";
    break;
case 3:
    suffix = "three";
    break;

    //ETC

default: break;
}
```

However, if you wish for a much larger range of numbers, I recommend you check out the following page:
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0426.html

It contains a method which converts a number to a word. It converts into the billions.

Regarding the suffix, a similar solution to that of above can be used. Watch out for 11, 12 and 13 though, because they have their unique suffixes.

```
String GetSuffix (int number)
{
    int lastTwoDigits = number % 100;

    if (lastTwoDigits == 11 || lastTwoDigits == 12 || lastTwoDigits == 13)
    {
        return "th";
    }

    switch (number % 10)
    {
    case 1:
        suffix = "st";
        break;
    case 2:
        suffix = "nd";
        break;
    case 3:
        suffix = "rd";
        break;
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
    case 0:
        suffix = "th";
        break;

    default: break;
    }

    //This shouldn't happen
    return "";
}
```

Here's an example of how to use this:

```
String result = "On the " + Integer.toString(day) + GetSuffix(day) + " day of holidays, I did " + EnglishNumberToWords(day) + " jumping jacks";
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop is not required, you can do it as follows:

```
int day = in.nextInt();

switch(day){
    case 10:
        System.out.println("statement 10");       
    case 9:
        System.out.println("statement 9");
    case 8:
        System.out.println("statement 8");
    case 7:
        System.out.println("statement 7");
    case 6:
        System.out.println("statement 6");
    case 5:
        System.out.println("statement 5");
    case 4:
        System.out.println("statement 4");
    case 3:
        System.out.println("statement 3");
    case 2:
        System.out.println("statement 2");
    case 1:
        System.out.println("statement 1");
    }
```

So, when the input is 8, it will print your all statements starting from 8 to 1 as you require.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I know how to print standard S.o.p statements but how will I check for the suffix using another switch

Comment: @user3353723 With this approach you wouldn't need to check the suffix. The string given to each println would be the complete string for each case. E.g. `case 8: System.out.println("On the 8th day of holidays, I did Eight jumping jacks,");` Note that this relies on the fall-through of case statments, which might not be considered good style.

Comment: @user3353723 yes its fall-through and it will print all the cases starting from the matching one. In general programming scenario, we don't have such requirements and you can consider it as a sample only to understand the language.

Answer (score 1):

Use methods for each operation. Each method will have its own switch:

```
private String getDaySuffix(int day) {
    switch(day) {
    case 1: return "st";
    // ...
    }
}

private String getActivity(int day) {
    switch(day) {
    case 1: return "One downhill sprint";
    // ...
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < day; i++) {
    String s = "On the " + day + getDaySuffix(day) + 
               " day of holidays, I did " + getActivity(day);
}
```

That way, you improve cohesion: each method does what it is supposed to do, and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Assume day has value entered by user.. then..

```
for(int i=day;i<=day && i!=0;i--)
{
switch(i)
{
case 8 :
On the 8th day of holidays, I did Eight jumping jacks,
break;
.
.
.

case 3 :
On the 3rd day of holidays, I did Three pull downs,
break;
.
.

case 1 :
On the 1st day of holidays, I did One downhill sprint.
break;

default :
break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the right suffix you could use a **switch**:

```
private static String getSuffix(final int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 0: throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        case 1: return "st";
        case 2: return "nd";
        case 3: return "rd";
        default:return "th";
    }
}
```

To geht the word form of a number you could use an **array**:

```
final static String[] numbers = new String[] {
        "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", 
        "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"
};
```

To use this, just append `numbers[yourInt]` to your string.
`numbers[5]` e.g. will be `"five"`.

Putting everything together might look like this *(It also appends an `s` to the activity if needed)*:

```
public class Main {
    final static String[] numbers = new String[] {
            "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", 
            "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"
    };

    final static String  pattern = "On the %d%s day of holidays, I did %s %s%s\n";
    final static Scanner in      = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int    day = in.nextInt();
        final String activity;

        switch (day) {
            case 1  : activity = "downhill sprint";  break;
            // ...
            case 3  : activity = "pull down";        break;
            //...
            case 8  : activity = "jumping jack";     break;
            default : activity = "";
        }

        if (!activity.equals(""))
            System.out.printf(pattern, day, getSuffix(day), numbers[day], activity, day > 1 ? "s" : "");

    }

    private static String getSuffix(final int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 0: throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            case 1: return "st";
            case 2: return "nd";
            case 3: return "rd";
            default:return "th";
        }
    }
}
```