# Convert numbers to rank

Tags: java, icu4j

I need to convert a number to its rank.

1 -> "First"

2 -> "Second"

3 -> "Third"

- %simplified (this gives 'one', 'two', 'three' etc.)
- %default (this gives 'one', 'two', 'three' etc.)
- %main (this gives 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc.)

The code in first link throws an exception (for rule set **"%simplified-ordinal"**) that it is unknown 'rule-set'

The question is already asked on SO (link below) and tried one of its solution but did not work.

Links I've already referred to are:

- [Is there a way in Java to convert an integer to its ordinal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810336/is-there-a-way-in-java-to-convert-an-integer-to-its-ordinal)
- http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/RuleBasedNumberFormat.html
- http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/numbers

I believe there is some 'rule-set' I need to pass to get what I'm looking for, but I'm not able to find it.

Comment: What about using enums? it may solve the "First"=1 "Second"=2 if you define it correctly.

Comment: The solution of JFK on that first link didn't work for you?

```
RuleBasedNumberFormat nf = new RuleBasedNumberFormat(Locale.UK, RuleBasedNumberFormat.SPELLOUT);
for(int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
{
    System.out.println(i + " -> "+nf.format(i, "%spellout-ordinal"));
}
```