# Convert ordinal number to string

Tags: java, android, ordinals

I am retrieving ordinal numbers using below code:

```
public static String ordinal(int i) {
    String[] sufixes = new String[] { "th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th" };
    switch (i % 100) {
    case 11:
    case 12:
    case 13:
        return i + "th";
    default:
        return i + sufixes[i % 10];

    }
}
```

Output :
1st, 2nd, 3rd...

How can I get string like first, second, third from these ordinal numbers in java, Android.

Comment: I am able to get ordinal number like above already using switch (i%100)

Ordinal String :: 0th
Ordinal String :: 1st
Ordinal String :: 2nd

Comment: Are you looking for a number ordinals like 1st,2nd,3rd like?

Comment: no. That already I am getting. 
I want string like first, second, third..

Comment: Are you looking like this 1 -> "First"
2 -> "Second"
3 -> "Third"

Comment: yes. 
If  it is possible using numbers like 1,2,3 to first, second, third.. will also be OK

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/33566603/3505534

Comment: I have already tried from this link:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810336/is-there-a-way-in-java-to-convert-an-integer-to-its-ordinal

 but It is giving me errors

Comment: @R2R I have used code from same link. but not getting result  what I want

Comment: @M.Prokhorov  I  have used code from same link. but not getting result what I want

Comment: There are answers to that question that do provide alternatives to spell it out.

Comment: @Frank, because you need to use ideas from answers, not code from answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this class I wrote. Just [download](https://gist.github.com/LeoAso/68097bfdb48b39317032433ed777671c) the file (license header included) to your project, update the package declaration, and you can use it like this.

```
Numerals ns = new Numerals();
System.out.println(ns.toWords(12048));
System.out.println(ns.toWords(12048, true));
System.out.println(ns.toWords(102500, false));
System.out.println(ns.toWords(102500, true));
```

which outputs

twelve thousand and forty-eight
twelve thousand and forty-eighth
one hundred and two thousand, five hundred
one hundred and two thousand, five hundredth

The second argument to `toWords`, if specified, determines whether to output ordinals (true) or regular numerals (false). You can take a look at it to see how it works.

Comment: This worked for me.. Thank you.

Comment: That is an extremely poor solution when it comes to Android, as it lacks internationalization.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov quite true. The OP would probably have been much better off using a full featured library. But I had the code anyway, so I thought I'd just share it. Plus, I missed the `android` tag when I first answered.