# Using concat with an int? (java)

Tags: java, concatenation

I am trying to do the following:

If a number between 1 and 100 is entered by the user, then:

- Print out each ordinal from 1 to the given number.

Example below is for the input value of 25:

```
1st
2nd
3rd
4th
5th
6th
7th
8th
9th
10th
11th
12th
13th
14th
15th
16th
17th
18th
19th
20th
21st
22nd
23rd
24th
25th
```

I can't figure out how to add the: `st, nd, rd, th` without using *`concat`*.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

   int userNum;
  userNum = scnr.nextInt();
  for (int i=1; i<=userNum; i++) {
  System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Is there another way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: What do you have against concat?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way in Java to convert an integer to its ordinal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810336/is-there-a-way-in-java-to-convert-an-integer-to-its-ordinal)

Comment: `System.out.print(i); System.out.println(theSuffix);`.

Comment: Can I use concat on an integer?

Comment: You'll want a String

Comment: You cannot concat an Integer at once. [String.concat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String)) takes a `String`as parameter. So you have to convert an Integer to `String` first.

Comment: See [How to concatenate int values in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674707/how-to-concatenate-int-values-in-java)

Comment: If all you're after is to **print** the results, you needn't resort to either `String.concat` or `+`:  print the number with `System.out.print` (_not_ `println`), then print the suffix with `System.out.println`.

Answer (score 1):

The special `String` concatentation operator (`+`) in Java will automatically convert scalars to strings (when the string is on the left). You could do something like this:

```
System.out.println(""+i+getPostfix(i));
```

where `getPostfix` would return an appropriate postfix for the given integer (-st, -nd, etc). I leave implementation of this function as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that with printf

```
for (int i=1; i<=userNum; i++) {
     System.out.printf("%d%s\n",i,i%10==1 && i>19 ? "st " : i%10==2 && i>19 ? "nd " : i%10==3 && i>19 ? "rd " : "th ");
}
```

Comment: This is really close but it results with the 11, 12, and 13 being 11st, 12nd, and 13rd.

Comment: that was a quick answer, you could elaborate for the rest.
i've updated the code for your convienience :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without using concat. You can check if number -st -nd -rd with modulo
( % 10)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {

private static final String DEFAULT_POSTFIX = "th";
private static final Map<Integer, String> POSTFIX_MAP =
        Stream.of(
                new SimpleEntry<>(1, "st"),
                new SimpleEntry<>(2, "rd"),
                new SimpleEntry<>(3, "nt"))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

private static String getPostfix(int number) {
    if (Arrays.asList(11,12,13).contains(number)) return DEFAULT_POSTFIX;
    return Optional
            .ofNullable(POSTFIX_MAP.get(number % 10))
            .orElse(DEFAULT_POSTFIX);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userNum = scanner.nextInt();
    IntStream
            .rangeClosed(1, userNum)
            .forEach(it -> System.out.println(it + getPostfix(it)));
}
```

}

Comment: It's not 11st, it's 11th. Same for 12th, 13th etc.

Comment: Same for 111th, 212th, 413th etc.

Comment: maybe, but she works with numbers between 1 to 100 (from the question)