# How can I format a number adding corresponding suffix to the end of it? - Java

Tags: java, android

I need in my text view to add a number, but also I need to add the corresponding suffix to that number like 1 is 1st, 2 is 2nd and so on. Is there any way to do this instead of writing a bunch of switch statements? The number is dynamic, so it doesn't have a range. Thank you.

Detailed description:

```
public String getNumberWithSuffix(int number) {
    /** Add an suffix to the end of the number, convert to string and return. 
        E.g. the number is 1, the suffix needs to be 'st', 
        so we concat them and return 1st. 
        If the number is 2, the suffix needs to be 'nd', 
        we concat them and return 2nd. 
        The range is not specified so it can be any integer number. 
    **/
}
```

Comment: your question is a vague description of an assignment, nothing more.

Comment: Yes, not clear to me also. Please elaborate

Comment: I can write this using switch statement, but I wondering maybe there's something that Java provides and we can use that to do so.

Comment: what do you mean by index? Is there any RecyclerView?

Comment: I think he means the additional letters like "st" to 1, "rd" to 3 etc

Comment: I've edited my question, hope it's clear now.

Comment: So you don't have to write switch cases for all numbers, just check for the last digit of the passed number. If last digit is 1 then append "st", if 2 then append "nd"and if 3 then append "rd" and  th otherwise (last else case)

Comment: @AsthaGarg actually I thought about it, but the thing is that for 11 the last number is also 1, but suffix is 'th'. 11th. In other cases seems it works.

Comment: Ya correct, so what I understand is for such exceptions you need to check them at starting. I don't see any in-built way in java so you need to handle manually. Basically 1 is exception not 11, 21 kind of numbers here

Comment: Yeah, seems so))

Comment: If you are asking what can replace a switch statement, I'd suggest a map. If you are asking if there is a library that already handles this, I dont know of one.

Answer (score 3):

Found an answer from similar question:-

```
public static String ordinal(int i) {
    String[] suffixes = new String[] { "th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th" };
    switch (i % 100) {
    case 11:
    case 12:
    case 13:
        return i + "th";
    default:
        return i + suffixes[i % 10];

    }
}
```

Link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6810409/8762338

Answer (score 1):

Something like this -

```java
// Initialize this as a singelton smwhere.
Map<Integer, String> suffixMapper = new HashMap<Integer, String>
suffixMapper.put(1, 'st');
suffixMapper.put(2, 'nd');
suffixMapper.put(3, 'rd');
```

```java
String getSuffix(int num) {
  if (num % 100 / 10 == 1) return "th"
  Integer lastDigit = num % 10
  String suffix = suffixMapper.get(lastDigit) != null ? suffixMapper.get(lastDigit) : "th";
  return suffix;
}
```

You can also make the map return an Optional to handle the null if needed.

If you are using Android, you can check this answer out -
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49384322/4983469