# how to have 'i' spelled out in a word instead of number format in java

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Instead of having java print out

```
Please enter the name for dog 1:
Please enter the name for dog 2:
Please enter the name for dog 3:
```

with code:

```
System.out.println("Please enter the name for the " + i + "dog");
String dogName = input.nextLine();
```

How can I get it to print out:

```
Please enter the name for the first dog.
Please enter the name for the second dog.
Please enter the name for the last dog.
```

I used:

```
System.out.println("Please enter the name for the " + i + "dog");
String dogName = input.nextLine();
```

but it don't want the numbers there, I want first, second, and last.

Comment: Possibly useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6810409/256196

Answer (score 2):

Well you need to convert your number into a word.

Use a series of `if` statements. See [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html).

```
String word = "";

if (i == 1) {
   word = "first";
}

if (i == 2) {
   word = "second";
}

if (i == 3) {
   word = "last";
}
```

Or use a `switch` for the same effect. See [tutorial for basic `switch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html), and see [JEP 361](https://openjdk.org/jeps/361) for switch expressions.

```java
String word = switch ( i )
{
    case 1 -> "first";
    case 2 -> "second";
    case 3 -> "last";
    default -> throw new IllegalStateException ( "Not 1-2-3." );
};
```

Then you can use your word in the message instead of `i`. See [tutorial on concatenating strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html).

```
System.out.println("Please enter the name for the " + word + " dog"); 
String dogName = input.nextLine();
```

Comment: @BasilBourque those additions are very kind of you.

Answer (score 0):

I would normally recommend a new class over parallel arrays, but this is a trivial case and parallel arrays would work almost exactly as you described. Something like,

```
String[] ordinals = { "first", "second", "last" };
String[] dogNames = new String[ordinals.length];
for (int i = 0; i < ordinals.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("Please enter the name for the %s dog%n", ordinals[i]);
    dogNames[i] = input.nextLine();
}
```

After the loop executes `dogNames` contains the names of the first, second and last dogs.

Comment: Given the level of the question, introducing something like `printf`` here is probably not the best idea.

Comment: @aroth I don't know. `printf("Hello, World\n");` was one of my first programs. I realize that *might **not*** be a point in favor.

Comment: Well, case in point. Here are [two](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/How-to-use-Java-printf-to-format-output) [articles](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/System-out-println-print-Java-meaning-explain-class-PrintStream-String-text) from the same publisher explaining `printf` and `println` respectively.  `printf` takes 1900 words, `println` under 500. I suspect the 1900-word `printf` explanation is inadequate. :)

Comment: @aroth K&R could have used `puts("Hello, World");` presumably they felt `printf` was important to introduce early. K&R is a *masterwork* in **terseness**.

Comment: But that's not a Java reference.  We don't know what the authors might have done if C had `println` too. Perhaps they avoided `puts` because its naming convention, while terse, is awful/completely opaque to the uninitiated.

Comment: @aroth That implies `printf` isn't awful/completely opaque to the uninitiated, I wouldn't go that far. Java has `String.format`, that isn't really ***better*** is it?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other suggestions, an array seems a natural solution.

```
static final String[] ordinal = { "first", "second", "last" };

System.out.println("Please enter the name for the " +
                   ordinal[i-1] + " dog");
```

(Use of "last" for "third" as per question).

(Checks for out-of-range `i` omitted).

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to make use of the [Ternary Operator](https://www.educative.io/answers/ternary-operator-in-java), for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    // Example of nested Ternary Operators:
    System.out.println("Please enter the name for the " 
            + (i == 0 ? "first" : (i == 1 ? "second" : "last")) + " dog");
}
```

The output to the Console Window will be:

```
Please enter the name for the first dog
Please enter the name for the second dog
Please enter the name for the last dog
```

**A usable example might be:**

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
String ls = System.lineSeparator();
String[] dogNames = new String[3];
String dName;
        
for (int i = 0; i < dogNames.length; i++) {
    dName = "";
    while (dName.isEmpty()) {
        // Example of nested Ternary Operators:
        System.out.print("Please enter the name for the " 
                + (i == 0 ? "first" : (i == 1 ? "second" : "last")) + " dog: -> ");
        dName = userInput.nextLine().trim();
        if (dName.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("You must enter a dog name! Try again..." + ls);
        }
    }
    dogNames[i] = dName;
}
        
System.out.println(ls + "Dog names provided are:" + ls 
                        + "-----------------------");
for (String names : dogNames) {
    System.out.println(names);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the *[ordinal indicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator)* instead.

```java
String suffix(int i) {
    return switch (i) {
        case 11, 12, 13 -> "th";
        default -> switch (i % 10) {
            case 1 -> "st";
            case 2 -> "nd";
            case 3 -> "rd";
            default -> "th";
        };
    };
}
```

Here is an example.

```java
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    System.out.print(i + suffix(i) + ' ');
```

Output

```
1st 2nd 3rd 4th 5th
```

Comment: Nice and general.