# How to convert any no. into word automatically

Tags: java, grails, groovy, grails-plugin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert number to words in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911966/how-to-convert-number-to-words-in-java)

For example if I write Rs."984" than it automatically convert into words like "Nine hundred and eighty four".

Comment: Please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911966/how-to-convert-number-to-words-in-java) previous SO post in which various methods which do what you are asking are described.

Comment: Please indicate whether this is a homework related question.

Comment: No, this is related to showing invoice, when I enter any amount in no format than convert into word format.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911966/how-to-convert-number-to-words-in-java