# Couldn't translate Date to spanish with Locale("es_ES")

Tags: java, date, locale

I'm trying to do a simple date format, it does work great, it's very easy, but the problem is the language. I used the locale "es_ES" to get "Miércoles" instead of "Wednesday" and sorts like that but i failed.

Here's my code:

```
SimpleDateFormat formato = 
    new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE d 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy", new Locale("es_ES"));
String fecha = formato.format(new Date());
```

The EXPECTED value of the `fecha` string is:

> Miércoles 4 de Abril de 2012

but i'm still getting:

> Wednesday 4 de April de 2012

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is the spanish locale available in `Locale.getAvailableLocales()`

Comment: a good tip to get in mind, thanks

Comment: Just `Locale.of("es");`
See the new i18n onward java19:  https://simplelocalize.io/blog/posts/java-internationalization/

Answer (score 95, accepted):

"es_ES" is a language + country.  You must specify each part separately.

The constructors for [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) are:

- [Locale(String language)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#Locale-java.lang.String-)
  Construct a locale from a language code.
- [Locale(String language, String country)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#Locale-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)
  Construct a locale from language, country.
- [Locale(String language, String country, String variant)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#Locale-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)
  Construct a locale from language, country, variant.

You want `new Locale("es", "ES");` to get the Locale that goes with es_ES.

However, it would be better to use [`Locale.forLanguageTag("es-ES")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#forLanguageTag-java.lang.String-), using the well-formed IETF BCP 47 language tag `es-ES` (with `-` instead of `_`), since that method can return a cached `Locale`, instead of always creating a new one.

Comment: worked great, thank you very much, i must have looked the constructors

Comment: What exactly is the variant for?

Comment: @JoseSerodio There are only 5 locales using variant: `en_US_POSIX: English (United States,Computer)`, `no_NO_NY: Norwegian (Norway,Nynorsk)`, `th_TH_TH_#u-nu-thai: Thai (Thailand,TH)`, `ja_JP_JP_#u-ca-japanese: Japanese (Japan,JP)`, `ca_ES_VALENCIA: Catalan (Spain,Valencian)`

Answer (score 7):

## tl;dr

```
String output = 
    ZonedDateTime.now ( ZoneId.of ( "Europe/Madrid" ) )
    .format ( 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate ( FormatStyle.FULL )
                         .withLocale ( new Locale ( "es" , "ES" ) ) 
    )
;
```

> martes 12 de julio de 2016

## Details

The [accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10019105/642706) by Affe is correct. You were incorrectly constructing a `Locale` object.

### java.time

The Question and Answer both use old outmoded classes now supplanted by  the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`. See [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

These classes include the [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to control the format of text when generating a String from your date-time value. You *can* specify an explicit formatting pattern. But why bother? Let the class automatically localize the format to the human language and cultural norms of a specific `Locale`.

For example, get the current moment in [Madrid regional time zone](http://time.is/Madrid).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Madrid" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId );
// example: 2016-07-12T01:43:09.231+02:00[Europe/Madrid]
```

Instantiate a formatter to generate a String to represent that date-time value. Specify the length of the text via [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) (full, long, medium, short).

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate ( FormatStyle.FULL );
```

Apply a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to [substitute for](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withLocale-java.util.Locale-) the JVM’s [current default](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault--) `Locale` assigned to the formatter.

```
Locale locale = new Locale ( "es" , "ES" );
formatter = formatter.withLocale ( locale );
```

Use the formatter to generate a String object.

```
String output = zdt.format ( formatter );
// example: martes 12 de julio de 2016
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "zdt: " + zdt + " with locale: " + locale + " | output: " + output );
```

> zdt: 2016-07-12T01:43:09.231+02:00[Europe/Madrid] with locale: es_ES | output: martes 12 de julio de 2016

Comment: Padding each parenthesis with whitespace looks cursed.

Comment: @AndrewLalis It's 2020, with 4K, 5K, 6K screens. We no longer need to code like it’s 1978, crammed on an [80-character terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100).

Comment: @BasilBourque I can't reach my pocket to put my mobile with a 4k screen from 2020 xD

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
String day = today.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, new Locale("es","ES")));
```

Also works for month.

Answer (score 3):

```
Locale spanishLocale=new Locale("es", "ES");
    String dateInSpanish=localDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, dd MMMM, yyyy",spanishLocale));
    System.out.println("'2016-01-01' in Spanish: "+dateInSpanish);
```

Comment: It doesn’t give the output asked for. Anyway upvoted for the demonstration of the use of java.time, the modern Java date and time API (as the third answer doing that).

Answer (score 2):

```
    Locale esLocale = new Locale("es", "ES");//para trabajar en español
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(strFormatoEntrada, esLocale);//El formato con que llega mi strFecha más el lenguaje
```