# How to convert date into marathi using SimpleDateFormat?

Tags: simpledateformat

How to convert **date** into marathi using `SimpleDateFormat`?
I tried using following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMM yyyy",new Locale("mr", "mr_IN"));
String newDate = df.format(d);
```

But its not working.

Comment: How is a marathi date? What do you get when you try that code?

Comment: its returning date in english

Comment: Did you read this? is from a different language but it is the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019050/couldnt-translate-date-to-spanish-with-localees-es

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two observations. **First** I assume your Locale-constructor is not used properly. Instead of:

```
new Locale("mr", "mr_IN")
```

you should rather try

```
new Locale("mr", "IN")
```

Explanation: The constructor expects as second argument the ISO-3166-country code in two big letters (and as first argument the ISO-639-language code in two small letters), see Javadoc.

**Second:**

On my system I printed out all available locales using `Locale.getAvailableLocales()` but was not lucky to see the locale "mr_IN". I hope for you to have a better localized Java configuration. If marathi language is not natively supported then you can finally try following:

```
DateFormatSymbols dfs =
  DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(new Locale("mr", "IN"));
dfs.setShortMonths(marathiMonthsAsArray);
dfs.setWeekdays(marathiWeekdays);

simpleDateFormat.setDateFormatSymbols(dfs);
```

Please carefully construct your marathi-language arrays with the proper lengths and indices - study the javadoc closely to avoid some pitfalls. Having done this then you can run your SimpleDateFormat code as marathi-localized.