# How to convert numbers in a date into words (e.g. 2012 Two Thousand Twelve)?

Tags: java, calendar

```
    import java.text.*; //SimpleDateFormat
    import java.util.*; //Date

    class MyClass
    {
        public static void main (String[] args)
        {
            SimpleDateFormat sdt = new SimpleDateFormat ("d-y-M");
            Date today = new Date();

            String msg = sdt.format(today);

            System.out.println(msg);
        }
    }
```

This code gives output : "31-2012-12"..
but I want as below :
"Thirty One - Two thousand twelve - Twelve"..

Comment: I'd create something that parses the numbers and creates this text personally. I dont think there is anything in the core libraries that do this and it shouldnt be too hard to do yourself

Comment: http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Java-Beginners/24697-convert-date-month-and-year-into-word-using-java.html has some rather C like code to do this for you

Comment: You may convert it to a number then use this post as a reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911966/how-to-convert-number-to-words-in- to convert the numbers to words.

Comment: Yep, I made my own quite easily

Comment: @RNJ Yep I am agree, I think better to use Enum

Comment: +1 for proposing `Enum` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding my comment as an asnwer:

You may convert it to a number then use this post as a reference: [How to convert number to words in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911966/how-to-convert-number-to-words-in-java) to convert numbers to words.

Answer (score 0):

http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/44180-converting-numbers-words.html

It's a C algorithm, but it should give you the idea. Please, next time try to show a bit of effort before submitting a question.