# set long values in a textfield

Tags: java, swing, numbers, jtextfield, mouse-listeners

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert number to words in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911966/how-to-convert-number-to-words-in-java)

I am trying to set the long value in the textfield the modification of my code is as below error what it is showing is required long found int

```
 private void jTextField2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        if(evt.getSource()==jTextField2){
            long jml = Long.parseLong(jTextField3.getText());

            jTextField1.setText(numberToWord(jml));

        }
    }
```

Comment: i actually updated some coding part and reposted it

Answer (score 0):

The [NumberFormatException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) is `Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have the appropriate format.` So, the exception could be because the maximum value of a java `int` is 2,147,483,647 (which is a 10-digit integer).

Answer (score 0):

The error is occuring in the below line, And looks like you are using [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) method in the below line,

```
at myproj.Certificates.jTextField2MouseClicked(Certificates.java:268)
```

When the value that is being passed to the method `Integer.parseInt()` is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (2,147,483,647), you will receive the `java.lang.NumberFormatException`.

And since 10000000000 is greater than 2,147,483,647 you are getting the NumberFormatException.

Comment: So use long, Long.parseLong.

Comment: long jml = Long.parseLong.(jTextField3.getText());
        i tried above but its showing identifier expected error

Comment: long jml = Long.parseLong.(jTextField3.getText()); i tried above but its showing identifier expected error

Comment: Are you using DOT (.) before ......(jTextField3.getText()); ..... If yes remove the same

Comment: ya done but now its showing required long found int error