# Convert int Value to a Different String Value

Tags: java, string, integer, type-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert number to words in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911966/how-to-convert-number-to-words-in-java)

I have some Java code that takes arguments, converts them to int values, does a little bit of math on them and then outputs them as int values up to 10. I need to take these output int values and convert them to another string.

For example:

```
int a = 6;
int b = a + 2;
System.out.print(b);
```

That will print the value 8. I know that I can convert int b to a string:

```
int a = 6;
int b = a + 2;
String b1 = Integer.toString(b);
System.out.print(b1);
```

This will turn my int b into String b1, but the output will still be 8. Since my values will only be a number 1 through 10 inclusive, how do I convert these values to their string counterpart (1 = one, 2 = two, etc.) I know that I'll have to declare that the value 8 is String eight, but I cannot figure it out. Am I even going down the right path?

Comment: I would use a `String[]` containing zthe Strings "one", "two" ... And than use the `int` 'b' as index to get the wanted String from the array.

Comment: Consider looking at [this chapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) in the Oracle Java tutorial.

Comment: Either use the string array or just have a static map to do the int based lookup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
String[] asString = new String[] { "zero", "one", "two" };    
int num = 1;
String oneAsString = asString[num]; // equals "one"
```

Or better put:

```
public class NumberConverter {
  private static final String[] AS_STRING = new String[] { "zero", "one", "two" };    

  public static String getTextualRepresentation(int n) {
    if (n>=AS_STRING.length || n<0) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("That number is not yet handled");
    }
    return AS_STRING[n];
  }
}
```

--

Edit see also: [How to convert number to words in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911966/how-to-convert-number-to-words-in-java)

Comment: Your answer makes sense, but I've only had about three weeks of programming. Someone commented on using switch statements which seems a bit easier to implement. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different ways of doing it. My personal preference is something like.

```
String text[] = {"zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven",
    "eight","nine","ten"};

void printValue(int val, int off)
{
   //Verify the values are in range do whatever else
   System.out.print(text[val+off]);
}
```