# Array of map? integer string value pair mapping

Tags: java, collections

I need to create a `Integer` and `String` paring, like

```
(1,one)
(2,two)
(3,three)
```

Later i want to iterate over it and get the `String` for a specific `Integer` value,
say like
if int `val == 2`, return String.

How can i do this?

Comment: So you want a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)?

Comment: Sounds like you're solving the wrong problem. How about this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3911966/139010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could model this pairing association by using a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

```
Map m = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
m.put(1, "one");
m.put(2, "two");
m.put(3, "three");

// Iterate the keys in the map
for (Entry<Integer, String> entry : m.entrySet()){
    if (entry.getKey().equals(Integer.valueOf(2)){
        System.out.println(entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Take into account that by definition of `Map`, you couldn't have two different Strings for a given Integer. If you wanted to allow this, you should use a `Map<Integer, List<String>>` instead.

Notice that java doesn't provide a `Pair` class, but you could implement one yourself:

```
public class Pair<X,Y> { 
    X value1;
    Y value2;
    public X getValue1() { return value1; }
    public Y getValue2() { return value2; }
    public void setValue1(X x) { value1 = x; }
    public void setValue2(Y y) { value2 = y; }
    // implement equals(), hashCode() as needeed
}
```

And then use an `List<Pair<Integer,String>>`.

Answer (score 0):

`Map<Integer,String> map = ...`

then when you want to iterate over the keys, use

`map.keySet()` to get a list of Integers used as keys