# Java : String representation from Integer

Tags: java

I'm having a list of `Integer` from 1 to 100. If I loop through the list, I wanted to make the output as,

"One"

"Two" .....

"Hundred"

Is there any direct method in Java to obtain the above output?

Comment: I don't think there's any built-in method to translate integers to English words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such method or class has been provided by JDK.

You can use the code mentioned [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0426.html) or [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/numberreader/) for reference purpose.

Answer (score 0):

switch case are used to meet that requirement: [Here](http://sarathantony.blogspot.in/2013/07/figure-to-words-converting-program-in.html)
is source code.
Answer of this question described here: [How to convert number to words in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911966/how-to-convert-number-to-words-in-java)

Officially this is not possible or no standard library available by native Java.

Don't duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

There is none in the official Java libraries.  However, the [International Components for Unicode](http://site.icu-project.org) project has a [RuleBasedNumberFormat](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/RuleBasedNumberFormat.html) with those capabilities.  It even has a [SPELLOUT](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/RuleBasedNumberFormat.html#SPELLOUT) constant.