# Java: Converting Double to String of Words

Tags: java, string, double

I am reading the number of lines in a file. I have this coming as a double by that maybe the last line is not complete. I need to output the number of lines as a string of words. What would be a good way to do this?

```
Double 850.25
```

goes to
    "Eight hundred and fifty and a fourth lines"

Comment: Can you clarify by showing an example of expected output?

Comment: You mean like "twenty thousand three hundred and forty five"?

Comment: Ingo, yes that is correct. See my above edit

Comment: If that's the case, it seems there's at least a couple of posts on SO about number-to-word conversion. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911966/how-to-convert-number-to-words-in-java), I think, might be helpful.

Comment: @PaulRichter Will this also do decimals?

Comment: @tucker19 Depends on which solution you go with; you'll have to see. If you use one of the custom solutions posted in the answers, if it doesn't handle decimals, you might have to program that modification yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your answer. think it could be helpful.

```
public class CashWordConverter {

public static final String[] units = {
    "", " one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven",
    "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen",
    "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"
};

public static final String[] tens = {
    "", // 0
    "", // 1
    "twenty", // 2
    "thirty", // 3
    "forty", // 4
    "fifty", // 5
    "sixty", // 6
    "seventy", // 7
    "eighty", // 8
    "ninety" // 9
};

public static String doubleConvert(final double n) {
    String pass = n + "";
    StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(pass, ".");
    String first = token.nextToken();
    String last = token.nextToken();
    try {
        pass = convert(Integer.parseInt(first))+" ";
        pass=pass+"POINT";
        for (int i = 0; i < last.length(); i++) {
            String get=convert(Integer.parseInt(last.charAt(i)+""));
            if(get.isEmpty()){
            pass=pass+" "+"ZERO";
            }else{
            pass=pass+" "+get;    
            }
        }

    } catch (NumberFormatException nf) {
    }
    return pass;
}

public static String convert(final int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        return "minus " + convert(-n);
    }

    if (n < 20) {
        return units[n];
    }

    if (n < 100) {
        return tens[n / 10] + ((n % 10 != 0) ? " " : "") + units[n % 10];
    }

    if (n < 1000) {
        return units[n / 100] + " hundred " + ((n % 100 != 0) ? " " : "") + convert(n % 100);
    }

    if (n < 1000000) {
        return convert(n / 1000) + " thousand " + ((n % 1000 != 0) ? " " : "") + convert(n % 1000);
    }

    if (n < 1000000000) {
        return convert(n / 1000000) + " million " + ((n % 1000000 != 0) ? " " : "") + convert(n % 1000000);
    }

    return convert(n / 1000000000) + " billion " + ((n % 1000000000 != 0) ? " " : "") + convert(n % 1000000000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From double to String :

`String doubleInString = "" + double;`

Or more intended to do this :

`String.valueOf(double)`  @DwB

is that what you want ?

From String to double :

```
try
{
    Double.parseDouble(myString)
}catch( Exception e )
{
   // what you want in case of error
}
```

From double to words :

You can use RuleBasedNumberFormat but I never tried so good luck :)

Comment: You could just do `String.valueOf(double)` instead; same result, but no need for concatenation.

Comment: @DwB lol not so terrible XD but I will add this way ^^ more intended to do it that's true :)

Comment: concatination is fine if you are concatenating multiple things.  doubleString = "not empty" + doubleValue;

Comment: Not for sure if this is it. I want to change Double 850 to Eight Hundred and Fifty

Answer (score -2):

```
Update (Mahbubur Rahman Khan) response,
Conversion of the second part will be better.   

public static String doubleConvert(final double n) {
            if (n == 0d) {
                return "0.0";
            }
            String          pass  = n + "";
            StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(pass, ".");
            String          first = token.nextToken();
            String          last  = token.nextToken();
            try {
                pass = convert(Integer.parseInt(first)) + " ";
                pass = pass + "point";
                if (Integer.parseInt(last) > 0){
                    pass = pass + " " + convert(Integer.parseInt(last));
                } else {
                    pass = pass + " " + "zero";
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException nf) {
                // error infos
            }
            return pass.replace("  ", " ");
        }
```