# Convert date to full text

Tags: java, oracle, date, datetime, date-format

In an application for public administration (formal documents, etc.), I need to change Date to full text (I don't know the English expression to say this).

For example, for an input like this (**04/05/2014**, with dd/MM/yyyy format) I need this output:

- In English: **Two thousand fourteen, May, fourth** (maybe twenty fourteen)
- In Spanish: **cuatro de mayo de dos mil catorce**

Is there anyway to do this in Java or Oracle?
I dont't refer to a custom implementation, but any library (Java, joda-time, etc.) or built-in Oracle Function...

Thank you very much. Regards

Comment: I don't think there are any multi-language built in functions.  Related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911966/how-to-convert-number-to-words-in-java

Comment: @gilbert-le-blanc , thank you. You put me on the way: finally I have had to make my custom methods to make the Spanish conversion. The related question you told contains very good suggestions too. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Oracle spell it out by specifying `SP` in the format model.

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate,'DDsp MON DAY YYYYsp') from dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DDSPMONDAYYYYYSP')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FIVE MAY MONDAY    TWO THOUSAND FOURTEEN
```

And, Also like this. using `SPTH`

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate,'DDspth MON DAY YYYYsp') from dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DDSPTHMONDAYYYYYSP')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FIFTH MAY MONDAY    TWO THOUSAND FOURTEEN
```

Comment: very very good suggestion, but it does not work for me, because of the language. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDateFormat: 
SimpleDateFormat is a concrete class for formatting and parsing dates in a locale-sensitive manner. It allows for formatting (date -> text), parsing (text -> date), and normalization.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

I hope it helps you

Comment: thank you, but SimpleDateFormat only works for the month with Locale. It does not seem to convert day of month and year into text.