# getting different outputs from the same object

Tags: java

I will call readInput() for the two different objects. But in the first i want to get output as "for the first line" , in the second i want to get output as "for the second line". How can i do? Thanks .

```
import java.util.*;

public class Nokta{

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    public void readInput()
    {
        System.out.println("for the first line ");
        String degerler = keyboard.nextLine();
    }
```

I will call like this:

```
Nokta dogru1 = new Nokta ();

dogru1.readInput();


Nokta dogru2 = new Nokta ();

dogru2.readInput();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
public  static int counter = 1;
   public void readInput()
   {
       System.out.println("for the "+counter +"line ");
       String degerler = keyboard.nextLine();
       counter++;
   }
```

more information : Static variable’s value is same for all the object(or instances) of the class

Comment: You need to increment the counter. If I'm not wrong !

Comment: Of course, this will output "for the 1 line" and "for the 2 line" instead of "for the first line" and "for the second line".

Answer (score 1):

You need to use static int for this. In short terms static will be initialized only once in execution it will not be initialized every time you do `new Nokta()` For what is static and examples please read this [link](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/static-variable/).

```
public class Nokta{
    private static int lineNumber=1;    
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    public void readInput()
    {
        System.out.println("for the "+ lineNumber++ +" line ");
        String degerler = keyboard.nextLine();
    }
```

---

## EDIT :

As in the comments this will say "for the 1 line" and "for the 2 line" instead of "for the first line" and "for the second line".

If you want to have it as first you can follow [How to convert number to words in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911966/how-to-convert-number-to-words-in-java)

Comment: Of course, this will output "for the 1 line" and "for the 2 line" instead of "for the first line" and "for the second line".

Comment: @GriffeyDog Yes you are correct made an edit to notify that and added info how can you get it as word.