# how to convert numbers into words with deciaml

Tags: java, sql-server, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I am trying to convert an entry using a numeric stepper in flex into words to display in a textarea.

i.e  "89" as a value and in the text area the words "Eighty nine" are displayed.
for example

```
5000
five thousands
```

Comment: Have a look at [How to convert numbers to words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911966/how-to-convert-number-to-words-in-java) and see if you can reverse it

Comment: If you post a question that can be interpreted as "do this work for me" you aren't going to get very many replies that you are going to like.