# Enter single digit number as input. the output will be converted to words and if the input is 0, the program will exit

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Example: 
             Enter a single digit number:2
             You have entered number Two
             Enter a single digit number:4
             You have entered number Four
             Enter a single digit number:0
             You have entered number Zero
             the program will exit/quit..

Comment: Show something which you have coded so far.

Comment: `if(number == 0){ println("You have entered number one"); return; }`

Comment: ok but it has no conversion just basic

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the switch-case statement [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Something like:

```
switch(input){

  case 0: return;
  case 1: //do each case separately.
  case 2: // or
  default://do something here if you want to parse any number to text.
}
```

**UPDATE**: There is an answer to parse numbers into words [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911966/how-to-convert-number-to-words-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GetInputFromUser{
    public static void main(String args[]){
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number:");
          int s = in.nextInt();
  System.out.println("You entered number "+s);
}
```

}

Comment: You should post code as edit on question. not as answer. please see my answer as it was updated.

Answer (score -1):

You can use bellow code for your desire input output:

```
    Scanner conin=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter single digit number:");
      String[] array = {"exit/quit","one", "two", "three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"};
    int a=conin.nextInt();
    if(a<10){
     while (a!=0) {            
      System.out.println("You have entered number:"+array[a]);
      a=conin.nextInt();

    }
   System.out.println("Program "+array[a]);
   System.exit(0);   
    }else{
        System.out.println("not allow"); 
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: but the output dude is not converted to words T_T still number

Comment: Hi,now check my answer