# print all number 1 to 9999 in words using java

Tags: java

I am trying to **print all number 1 to 9999 in words using java**. I wrote below code

```
import java.util.*;
public class NubersTOWords {
    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter  number :");
        int num =obj.nextInt();
        int digit1,digit2;
        String st1[] ={ "",
                "one",
                "two",
                "three",
                "four",
                "five",
                "six",
                "seven",
                "eight",
                "nine","Ten","Eleven","Twelve","Thirteen","fourteen","Fifteen","Sixteen","Seventeen","Eighteen","Nineteen"};
        String st2[] ={"","","Twenty","Thirty","Forty","Fifty","Sixty","Seventy","Eighty","Ninety"};
        String st3[]={"Hundred","Thousand"};
    /*  
        if(num <0 || num>=100)
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong number");

        }*/
        if(num >1 && num <20 )
        {
            System.out.println(st1[num]);
        }
        else if(num >=20 && num <=99) 
        {
            digit1 =num/10;
            digit2 =num%10;
            System.out.println(st2[digit1]+" "+st1[digit2]);

        }
        else if(num >=100 && num <=9999) 
        {
            //Here how to change my code?
        }

    }

}
```

Above code satisfied the requirements 1-100 but how to full fill upto 9999.

How to complete the requirements from this code?

Code would be appreciable.

Comment: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0426.html

Comment: You already have the logic of dividing by 10 and taking the modulo. Do the same with 100, and you'll know how many hundreds are in the number. Do the same with 1000, and you'll know how many thousands there are.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using java8 then you can use this code:

```
public class PrintAllNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 9999)
        .mapToObj(i-> EnglishNumberToWords.convert(i))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

in combination with this great answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3911987/476791 :

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class EnglishNumberToWords {

  private static final String[] tensNames = {
    "",
    " ten",
    " twenty",
    " thirty",
    " forty",
    " fifty",
    " sixty",
    " seventy",
    " eighty",
    " ninety"
  };

  private static final String[] numNames = {
    "",
    " one",
    " two",
    " three",
    " four",
    " five",
    " six",
    " seven",
    " eight",
    " nine",
    " ten",
    " eleven",
    " twelve",
    " thirteen",
    " fourteen",
    " fifteen",
    " sixteen",
    " seventeen",
    " eighteen",
    " nineteen"
  };

  private EnglishNumberToWords() {}

  private static String convertLessThanOneThousand(int number) {
    String soFar;

    if (number % 100 < 20){
      soFar = numNames[number % 100];
      number /= 100;
    }
    else {
      soFar = numNames[number % 10];
      number /= 10;

      soFar = tensNames[number % 10] + soFar;
      number /= 10;
    }
    if (number == 0) return soFar;
    return numNames[number] + " hundred" + soFar;
  }


  public static String convert(long number) {
    // 0 to 999 999 999 999
    if (number == 0) { return "zero"; }

    String snumber = Long.toString(number);

    // pad with "0"
    String mask = "000000000000";
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(mask);
    snumber = df.format(number);

    // XXXnnnnnnnnn
    int billions = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(0,3));
    // nnnXXXnnnnnn
    int millions  = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(3,6));
    // nnnnnnXXXnnn
    int hundredThousands = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(6,9));
    // nnnnnnnnnXXX
    int thousands = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(9,12));

    String tradBillions;
    switch (billions) {
    case 0:
      tradBillions = "";
      break;
    case 1 :
      tradBillions = convertLessThanOneThousand(billions)
      + " billion ";
      break;
    default :
      tradBillions = convertLessThanOneThousand(billions)
      + " billion ";
    }
    String result =  tradBillions;

    String tradMillions;
    switch (millions) {
    case 0:
      tradMillions = "";
      break;
    case 1 :
      tradMillions = convertLessThanOneThousand(millions)
         + " million ";
      break;
    default :
      tradMillions = convertLessThanOneThousand(millions)
         + " million ";
    }
    result =  result + tradMillions;

    String tradHundredThousands;
    switch (hundredThousands) {
    case 0:
      tradHundredThousands = "";
      break;
    case 1 :
      tradHundredThousands = "one thousand ";
      break;
    default :
      tradHundredThousands = convertLessThanOneThousand(hundredThousands)
         + " thousand ";
    }
    result =  result + tradHundredThousands;

    String tradThousand;
    tradThousand = convertLessThanOneThousand(thousands);
    result =  result + tradThousand;

    // remove extra spaces!
    return result.replaceAll("^\\s+", "").replaceAll("\\b\\s{2,}\\b", " ");
  }

  /**
   * testing
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(0));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(1));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(16));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(100));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(118));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(200));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(219));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(800));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(801));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(1316));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(1000000));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(2000000));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(3000200));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(700000));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(9000000));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(9001000));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(123456789));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(2147483647));
    System.out.println("*** " + EnglishNumberToWords.convert(3000000010L));

    /*
     *** zero
     *** one
     *** sixteen
     *** one hundred
     *** one hundred eighteen
     *** two hundred
     *** two hundred nineteen
     *** eight hundred
     *** eight hundred one
     *** one thousand three hundred sixteen
     *** one million
     *** two millions
     *** three millions two hundred
     *** seven hundred thousand
     *** nine millions
     *** nine millions one thousand
     *** one hundred twenty three millions four hundred
     **      fifty six thousand seven hundred eighty nine
     *** two billion one hundred forty seven millions
     **      four hundred eighty three thousand six hundred forty seven
     *** three billion ten
     **/
  }
}
```