# Algorithm to convert 1 to "One" and so on in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I'm looking for an algorithm or function to convert integer number 0,1,2 to Zero,One,Two respectively. How can we do this in Objective-C ?

Comment: Single digits only? Localized or english only?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911966/how-to-convert-number-to-words-in-java. Here is an example of such code in java

Comment: @AdamM thanks buddy. I'll convert the code

Comment: [Here it is in Swift](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58878/int-extension-for-translating-integer-to-plain-english) which is probably a better starting point for doing an Objective-C translation.  And [here is an Objective-C attempt](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/59546/36366).

Comment: @rounak adamM commented right answer.

Comment: @Ashwin thanks I had in mind NSNumberformatter. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple has a lot of handy formatting functionality built in for many data types. Called a "formatter," they can convert objects to/from string representations.

For your case, you will be using NSNumberFormatter, but if you have an integer you need to convert it to an NSNumber first. See below example.

```
NSInteger anInt = 11242043;
NSString *wordNumber;

//convert to words
NSNumber *numberValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:anInt]; //needs to be NSNumber!
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle];
wordNumber = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:numberValue];
NSLog(@"Answer: %@", wordNumber);
// Answer: eleven million two hundred forty-two thousand forty-three
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my code for 0 to 100 (You can update as per your requirement). WORKING PERFECTLY !!

```
-(NSDictionary *)algorithm
{
    NSArray *myArray = @[@"Zero",@"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four",@"Five",@"Six",@"Seven",@"Eight",@"Nine",@"Ten",@"Eleven",@"Twelve",@"Thirteen",@"Fourteen",@"Fifteen",@"Sixteen",@"Sevteen",@"Eighteen",@"Nineteen"];

    NSArray *tensArray = @[@"Twenty",@"Thirty",@"Fourty",@"Fifty",@"Sixty"
                           ,@"Seventy",@"Eighty",@"Ninety",@"One Hundred"];

    NSMutableDictionary *numberStringDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *numberStringsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(int i=0;i<=100;i++)
    {

        if(i<20)
        {
            [numberStringDictionary setObject:myArray[i] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
            [numberStringsArray addObject:myArray[i]];
            NSLog(@"\n%@",myArray[i]);
        }
        else if(i%10==0)
        {
            [numberStringDictionary setObject:tensArray[i/10-2] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
            [numberStringsArray addObject:tensArray[i/10-2]];
            NSLog(@"\n%@",tensArray[i/10-2]);
        }
        else
        {
            [numberStringDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",tensArray[i/10-2],myArray[i%10]] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];

            [numberStringsArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",tensArray[i/10-2],myArray[i%10]]];

            NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",tensArray[i/10-2],myArray[i%10]]);
        }

    }
    return numberStringDictionary;
}
```