# Program convert number into words

Tags: java, math, numbers, jscience

Can i ask some help? I'm a newbie at programming. It's been a week since i started programming. I've been working on a program that require to input a number and to output the letter of the number you input. 
My question is. Is there any alternative code for this program? Also, How can i add some code if the input is -1 and it will read as "Negative one"? I really appreciate any help you guys can give.

This is the code i've been working:

The example Output is :
Enter number : 12345
Output : Twelve Thousand Three Hundred Fourty Five

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Numberconvert {

    public boolean Number(String s) {
        boolean tama = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return tama;
    }

    public static String convert(int digit) {
        String ArrayOnes[] = {"zero", " One ", " Two ", " Three ", " Four ", " Five ", " Six ", " Seven ", " Eight ", " Nine ", " Ten ",
             " Eleven ", " Twleve ", " Thirteen ", " Fourteen ", " Fifteen ", " Sixteen ", " Seventeen ", " Eighteen ", " Ninteen "};
        String ArrayOnes2[] = {" ", " Ten ", " Twenty ", " Thirty ", " Fourty ", " Fifty ", " Sixty ", " Seventy ", " Eighty ", " Ninety "};
        String ArrayNegative[] = {"Negative "};

        if (digit < 0) {
            return ArrayNegative[0];
        }
        if (digit % 10 == 0) {
            ArrayOnes[0] = "";
        }
        if (digit < 20) {
            return ArrayOnes[digit];
        }
        if (digit < 100) {
            return ArrayOnes2[digit / 10] + ArrayOnes[digit % 10];
        }
        if (digit < 10000) //return convert(digit/100)+" Hundred "+convert(digit %100);
        {
            return convert(digit / 100) + " Thousand " + convert(digit % 100);
        }
        if (digit < 100000000) {
            return convert(digit / 1000) + " Thousand " + convert(digit % 1000);
        }
        return convert(digit / 1000000000) + " Million " + convert(digit % 1000000000);
        //return convert(digit);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scann = new Scanner(System.in);
        String Number;

        // checker - class to loop until the input is number
        Numberconvert checkIfNumber = new Numberconvert();

        // convert string in to number
        int result;

        try {
            // this do while method is only to check if the input is Number 
            do {
                System.out.print("Enter a Number: ");
                Number = scann.nextLine();
            } while (!checkIfNumber.Number(Number));

            // this if statement is only works if the input is Number
            if (checkIfNumber.Number(Number)) {
                // String into int to process the String
                result = Integer.parseInt(Number);
                // initialize "converted" to the function;
                String converted = convert(result);
                // print the result
                System.out.println(converted);
            }

            // if ever some error detected. The user want to input again
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("");
            System.err.println("Some Errors Detected ");
            System.out.println("Want to input again? Press Enter ");
            scann.nextLine();
            main(null);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was already asked in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911966/how-to-convert-number-to-words-in-java)

And there is a [link to the sourcecode](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0426.html) (same as in answer 1)