# Android TalkBack for SeekBar values

Tags: android, seekbar, talkback, accessibility

So I have a `SeekBar` in my app and I'm using the TalkBack function of Android. When the `SeekBar` is scrolled, the device says "(android:contentDescription of view), SeekBar control, 50%". Is it possible to change it so it says the actual value (from -4 to +4), like "SeekBar control, negative 4"?

Comment: do you want to add those -4 and +4 to both sides or when you scroll display that value  eg 3.2

Comment: -4 to +4 is already displayed above the SeekBar control, but it is a different view so the values are not spoken as actual -4 to 4 but rather by percentage

Answer (score 8):

If you're using a SeekBar, I figure you're tracking the value somewhere. In our case, there is a TextView above the SeekBar that displays the current value derived from the SeekBar's progress.

I've found that setting `android:accessibilityLiveRegion="assertive"` as an attribute for the TextView works perfectly. It results an an announcement of the updated value (since the TextView is update), followed by the SeekBar's progress.

Note: Setting `android:accessibilityLiveRegion` to `assertive` was appropriate for us because it's less time consuming for a user to rapidly change the SeekBar's progress. Setting it to `polite` announces every increment, while `assertive` skips unannounced increments to the most recent.

[image: Example of what I'm talking about.]

Answer (score 2):

Though not the perfect answer, I found this useful method:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#announceForAccessibility(java.lang.CharSequence)

Which basically makes the TalkBack function talk during a specific event. I added this in the OnSeekBarChangeListener to make it "talk" every time I change the value of the slider.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, Its possible.

You said its showing "SeekBar control, 50%" means you are getting percentage.

So, use this percentage to achieve you goal:

```
int minValue = -4;
int maxValue = 4;
int diff = maxValue - minValue;
int realProgress = minValue + (diff * percentage / 100);
```

realProgress is your answer.

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Not really what I need. I already know this. My problem is that I want the TalkBack function to say the actual value of "zero" or whatsoever, not "50 percent"

Comment: You mean to say, actual value in words?

Comment: Yes, because now it only says the percentage like "50 percent"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911966/how-to-convert-number-to-words-in-java may helps you

Comment: This answer doesn't really answer the original question. This doesn't help talk balk at all.

Comment: @Pieces, This question is not about Talkback, real problem is value is coming in percentage and mugiwara wants it in real progress.

Comment: It's about talk back speaking percentages. Not displaying them.

Comment: @Pieces, its not about displaying or speaking. Problem is he wants progress value instead progress percentages. First understand the issue then comment over anyone's answer.

Comment: I have the same issue so I do understand the question. You should take your own advice. Look at the second comment under the question.

Comment: Same to you! ;)