# Numberic to text conversion using FTL

Tags: html, freemarker

I have `123` as the numeric value.

I need to print it as `one hundred twenty three`.

Is it possible in FTL, HTML?

Comment: No, you have to do it on your own in Java: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911966/how-to-convert-number-to-words-in-java

Answer (score 1):

HTML is a markup language, it does not do any computing. For computing you would be looking for a programming/scripting language such as Javascript, PHP, Java, etc.

Here is a deeper explanation

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-programming-languages-markup-languages-and-scripting-languages