# Avoiding rounding when doing calculation

Tags: java

I've a piece of Java code from here which converts a number to words, it's working fine but the fraction is always 1 less than it should be, ex. `122.11` is printed `122.10`.

Here is piece of code which is doing the calculation.
How can I solve this issue?

```
    String phrase = "122.11" ;
    Float num = new Float( phrase ) ;
    int dollars = (int)Math.floor( num ) ;
    int cent = (int)Math.floor( ( num - dollars ) * 100.0f ) ;
```

Comment: Could you please post the whole code of your's because this code is working fine and `num` contains two decimal digits

Comment: When I see `dollars` I would immediately use `BigDecimal` instead of `Float`.

Comment: Use `BigDecimal`

Comment: Please edit your code, to display the complete problem. the present code gives you 122 and 12 as expected

Comment: the full code could be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911966/how-to-convert-number-to-words-in-java

Answer (score 0):

```
String phrase = " 555243.22" ;
Double num = new Double( phrase ) ;
double dollarsAsDouble =  Math.floor( num ) ;
double val=num - dollarsAsDouble+0.005;
int cent = (int)Math.floor(val * 100.0f ) ;
int dollars=(int) dollarsAsDouble;
System.out.println(cent);//555234
System.out.println(dollars);//22
```

or:

```
String phrase = "122.12" ;
String[] val=phrase.split("\\.");
int dollars=new Integer(val[0]);
int cent=0;
if(val.length>1)
    cent=new Integer(val[1]);

System.out.println(cent);
System.out.println(dollars);
```

or:

```
String phrase = "555243.22" ;
BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(phrase);
num.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
BigDecimal result = num.subtract(new BigDecimal(num.longValue()));
System.out.println((int)(result.doubleValue()*100.0)); // 22
System.out.println(num.intValue());//555243
```

Comment: First solution is not ok when the amount get bigger like 555,243.22  then the .22 is printed .25 , second solution is working fine

Comment: @JAVADEV i fixed the first solution to work with bigger numbers.you need to use Double type and not Float type!

Comment: @JAVADEV I added third solution with BigDecimal

Answer (score 0):

`0.11` cannot be represented exactly in the floating point arithmetic, and ends up being 0.1099999something internally (`0.10999999999999943`, at least on my machine, but that should be universal). Multiply by 100 and floor it, and you get 10. You can easily circumvent this by rounding the 100-fold number, instead of flooring it, simply by adding 0.5 to the number you want to round. And, you can skip the `Math.floor()`, as casting the number to `int` already does what you want:

```
int cent = (int)( ( num - dollars ) * 100.0f + 0.5f) ;
```

Comment: this solution is giving wrong results when the number gets bigger, ex. 543,122.22 restult fraction is .25

Comment: Sure, but that follows from your choice of using `float`s. They give you only 6-7 significant decimal digits (24 binary digits, to be exact). If you used `double`, which is the default FP format in Java, you'd have 15 significant digits. If that isn't enough, e.g. because you are calculating the federal budget of the USA, I concur with other posters and suggest you use `BigDecimal`.