# Converting numbers into words from user input

Tags: java, string, loops, int

I've been trying to convert user's given number to words up to 999 in one popup sentence, but I can't get it to do so. The words keeps separating into different pop ups and it's not quite correct, what am I doing wrong? Help is much appreciated.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.*;

public class Program_6_2 {
   public static void main(String[] args)
   throws IOException {

      int number;
      int teen;
      int digits;

      number = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("please enter a positive integer < 1000; or 0 to quit: "));

      while (number != 0) {
         if (number>=0 && number<=999) {
            if (number == 0) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Program Terminated");
            }
            String ones[] = {" ", " one", " two", " three", " four", " five", " six", " seven", " eight", " nine", " ten",
               " eleven", " twelve", " thirteen", " fourteen", " fifteen", " sixteen", " seventeen", " eighteen", " nineteen"
            };
            String tens[] = {" ", " ", " twenty", " thirty", " fourty", " fifty", " sixty", " seventy", " eighty", " ninety"};

            teen = number/10;
            digits = number%10;

            if (number >= 100 & number<=999) {
               number = number/100;
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, number + " hundred" );
            }
            if (number > 19) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, tens[teen] + " " + ones[digits]);
            } else {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ones[number]);
            }
            //  else if (number <=0 && number >=1000) {
            //JOptionPane.showInputDialog(".... DATA ENTRY ERROR .... \n please enter a positive integer < 1000; or 0 to quit: ");

         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert number to words in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911966/how-to-convert-number-to-words-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Build your string answer first, then display it.

```
            StringBuffer numberString = new StringBuffer();
            if (number >= 100 & number<=999) {
                numberString.append(number/100).append(" hundred");
                number = number%100;
            }
            if (number > 19) {
                numberString.append(tens[number/10]).append(" ").append(ones[number%10]);
            } else {
                numberString.append(ones[number%10]);
        }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, numberString.toString());

        }
```