# How to output a specific column/value from a text file with split?

Tags: java, arrays, split, text-files, java.util.scanner

This is what I've got so far. I'm trying to use split so that it would print out a specific item (country names from the input file) but I'm not entirely sure how to do it and there's some errors where I'm doing the split.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        readFile("sample1.txt");
    }

    //creates a method that opens the file 
    public static void readFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File text = new File(fileName);
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(text);
        while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
            //splits the text file to print out specific columns
            String[] data = reader.nextLine().split("   ");
            System.out.println(data);
        }
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

Input file:

```
1   China   Japan   2   2   
2   Korea   India   2   2   
3   Korea   India   1   2   
4   Korea   Germany 1   2   
5   Japan   Germany 5   8   
6   India   Japan   5   8   
7   India   Japan   8   10  
8   China   Korea   6   9
```

Output I'm looking for:

```
Package one ships from China to Japan
Package two ships from Korea to India
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to split on 1 or more spaces, not on exactly 3 spaces, and hope that the names won't ever have embedded spaces.

You should use try-with-resources.

```java
public static void readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(Paths.get(fileName))) {
        while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = reader.nextLine().trim();
            if (line.isEmpty())
                continue; // Ignore blank lines
            String[] data = line.split(" +");
            if (data.length != 5)
                throw new IOException("Invalid line: " + line);
            int num = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
            String from = data[1];
            String to = data[2];
            System.out.printf("Package %s ships from %s to %s%n",
                              numberToWords(num), from, to);
        }
    }
}

private static String numberToWords(int num) {
    // TODO
    return String.valueOf(num);
}
```

Now you just need to implement the `numberToWords` method. See e.g. "[How to convert number to words in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3911966/5221149)" for how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post this answer with the possibility of dodging the real question,

but with `Scanner`, `Scanner.next()` gives the next string token, which is split by whitespace. No string splitting necessary.

So to get that line it would be

```java
int packageId = reader.nextInt();
String from = reader.next();
String to = reader.next();
```

Just make sure to do `reader.nextLine()` to clear the new line at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

One way to implement this in fewer lines of code can be by using `Files.lines` method as follows:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Files.lines(Path.of("sample1.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset())
                .forEach(line ->
                {
                    String message = getShippingMessage(line);
                    if(message.isEmpty()) return;
                    System.out.println(message);
                });
    }

    private static String getShippingMessage(String line) {
        String[] data = line.split(" +");
        if (data.length < 3) return "";
        int serialNum = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
        String origin = data[1];
        String destination = data[2];
        return String.format("Package %s ships from %s to %s", serialNum, origin, destination);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Package 1 ships from China to Japan
Package 2 ships from Korea to India
Package 3 ships from Korea to India
Package 4 ships from Korea to Germany
Package 5 ships from Japan to Germany
Package 6 ships from India to Japan
Package 7 ships from India to Japan
Package 8 ships from China to Korea
```

PS: For converting number to words you can follow the suggestion in Andreas answer.